# Saving Data Structures in C#

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm learning C# by writing a home library manager.

I have a BookController that will store the books in a data structure and perform operations on them.

Does C# have a way of saving the data in the dictionary to a local file perhaps in an XML fashion to load later, or am I going to have to write it myself?

What is the best method of saving and loading this data available to C#? Just need pointed in a good direction.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually, C# (the language) doesn't know **anything** about serialization, but .NET (the framework) provides lots of ways... `XmlSerializer`, `BinaryFormatter`, `DataContractSerializer` (.NET 3.0) - or there are a few bespoke serialization frameworks too.

Which to use depends on your requirements; `BinaryFormatter` is simple to use, but burns assembly metadata information into the file - making it non-portable (you couldn't open it in Java, for example). `XmlSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer` are primarily xml-based, making it quite portable, but fairly large unless you compress it.

Some proprietary serializers are half-way between the two; [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) is a binary formatter (so very dense data), but which follows a portable standard for the data format (Google's protocol buffers spec). Whether this is useful depends on your scenario.

Typical code (here using `XmlSerializer`):

```
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
        // write
        using (var stream = File.Create("foo.xml"))
        {
            ser.Serialize(stream, foo); // your instance
        }
        // read
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead("foo.xml"))
        {
            Foo newFoo = (Foo)ser.Deserialize(stream);
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Look at [Serialization](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/objserial.aspx) and the [ISerializable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx)

It allows you to save an object's state in a portable form.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your data to be in XML format there's [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx).

EDIT: For some reason I was downvoted for suggesting this because XmlSerializer cannot serialize a Dictionary.

To get around this problem you can always customize the serialization process like [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2006/07/09/generic-dictionaries-vs-the-xmlserializer/)

Comment: XmlSerializer is not able to serialize Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.

Comment: Who said this is what @Coyote is using? No need to down-vote, the answer is not *wrong*. Incomplete maybe, but then a hint alone suffices. There are ways to XML serialize a dictionary, if you hit that wall.

Comment: I see a dictionary as an internal look up optimization that doesn't need to be exposed in the data. i.e. if you dictionary key is a property in your object, then you are just bloating the payload by having it there twice and having the extra wrapper code. IMO it is  lazy drag-drop coder practice to serialize dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider looking at Linq to SQL (or Entity Framework) for O/R mapping and storing your data into a database (SQL CE, SQL Express).

Answer (score 1):

I've created an extension method which takes an object and creates an xml string for you, all you need to do is save/load from file.
[XmlSerialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/post-your-extension-goodies-for-c-net-codeplexcomextensionoverflow#271423)