# Delphi OpenDialog without letting the user navigate away from the inital dir

Tags: delphi, windows-7, fileopendialog

I am trying to create an open dialog (in Windows 7) where the user is confined to the initial directory. On the open dialog I have set the optionsEX to [ofExNoPlacesBar] and that removes the bar that would let them select folders and directories to go to quickly but the user can use the bread crumb address tool to go up a level and type a different directory into the filename text box to change directories.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Delphi 2009+, there is a `TFileOpenDialog`. Use this, and set

```
procedure TForm3.FileOpenDialog1FolderChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FInitiated := true;
end;

procedure TForm3.FileOpenDialog1FolderChanging(Sender: TObject;
  var CanChange: Boolean);
begin
  CanChange := not FInitiated;
end;

procedure TForm3.btnOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FInitiated := false;
  FileOpenDialog1.DefaultFolder := 'C:\MyFolder\';
  FileOpenDialog1.Execute;
end;
```

where

```
var
  FInitiated: boolean;
```

(Notice that there should be exactly one `FInitiated` per `TFileOpenDialog`. So, if `FileOpenDialog` is a private member of `TForm3`, let `FInitiated` be a private member of `TForm3` as well.)

To improve the user experience, you will probably use

```
procedure TForm3.FileOpenDialog1FolderChanging(Sender: TObject;
  var CanChange: Boolean);
begin
  CanChange := not FInitiated;
  if not CanChange then beep;
end;
```

or

```
procedure TForm3.FileOpenDialog1FolderChanging(Sender: TObject;
  var CanChange: Boolean);
begin
  CanChange := not FInitiated;
  if not CanChange then
    MessageBox(Handle, PChar('Directory selection is not allowed.'), PChar(Caption), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a different open dialog (make a form yourself with no folder navigation, only a file list box), or simply audit for a path not matching the initial dir and refuse to actually open the file.

Answer (score -1):

The 'FileOpenDialog' has an [`OnFolderChanging`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Dialogs_TCustomFileDialog_OnFolderChanging.html) event of type [`TFileDialogFolderChangingEvent`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Dialogs_TFileDialogFolderChangingEvent.html) which have a boolean `CanChange` parameter. I'd expect setting this parameter to false would serve the purpose.

**edit:**

Example usage as per Remy's comments (if I understood correctly);

```
procedure TForm1.FileOpenDialog1FolderChanging(Sender: TObject;
  var CanChange: Boolean);
var
  Dlg: TFileOpenDialog;
  DefFolder: IShellItem;
  iOrder: Integer;
begin
  CanChange := False;
  Dlg := Sender as TFileOpenDialog;
  if Succeeded(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(PWideChar(WideString(Dlg.DefaultFolder)), nil, IShellItem, DefFolder)) then
  try
    CanChange := Dlg.ShellItem.Compare(DefFolder, SICHINT_ALLFIELDS, iOrder) = S_OK;
  finally
    DefFolder := nil;
  end;
end;
```

The below also works but more vulnerable to path variations (see Andreas' comments below);

```
procedure TForm1.FileOpenDialog1FolderChanging(Sender: TObject;
  var CanChange: Boolean);
begin
  CanChange := SameFileName(TFileOpenDialog(Sender).FileName,
                            TFileOpenDialog(Sender).DefaultFolder);
end;
```

Comment: Yes, but setting this to the literal `false` will make it impossible for the dialog to open, because the initial directory needs to be set before the dialog opens!

Comment: @Andreas - CanChange could be set to false on the condition that the changing folder is not the predefined one, no?

Comment: @Sertac: No. When `FolderChanging` is called, the folder has not been changed yet, so how do you know if the new will be a different one or not?

Comment: @Andreas: When the `OnFolderChanging` event is fired, the dialog's `ShellItem` property points to an `IShellItem` interface that represents the folder being changed to, and the `FileName` property is set to the folder's fileystem path. You can compare those values against your dialog's `InitialDir` value to see if they match.

Comment: The code above, however, seems not to work. Maybe Sertac should try his code before posting it? :)

Comment: @Andreas - I did, both of the snippets work here. None or one of them does not work for you?

Comment: No, I do not see any dialog at all. It is like `Execute` was not called at all.

Comment: @Sertac: And do you know why? Because `"C:\WINDOWS" <> "C:\Windows"`. There is also a risk of having a "\" suffix, ".\", etc. So it is a rather volatile approach, unless one uses a more sophisticated `SameDir` function. If you do not, I think that my method is far safer.

Comment: @Andreas - Setting `DefaultFolder` to sth. like `C:\Program Files` before calling `Execute`?

Comment: @Sertac: Yes, I set it to "C:\WINDOWS".

Comment: @Andreas - Who said anything about `C:\WINDOWS`? <g> Well, since the file system is case insensitive I think Tim can handle it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Sertac: Your code still doesn't work. `SameFileName('C:\WINDOWS\', 'C:\Windows')` returns `false`, due to the backslash. Use `IncludeTrailingBackslash` in both arguments, please. Then I will finally give you a +1 !

Comment: @Andreas - Ha!, then there'll be `\..\ ` etc. in the path right? ;)   +1, so that your comment is visible. If one wants to code a robust `SameDir`, the questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562701/best-way-to-determine-if-two-path-reference-to-same-file-in-c-c/562773#562773 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684684/normalize-file-path-with-winapi should prove to be useful.

Comment: A better option is to obtain an `IShellItem` interface for the initial folder path via the `SHCreateShellItem()` or related function, and then use the `IShellItem.Compare()` method to compare it with the dialog's `ShellItem` property.  This way, there are no issues with slashes, character casing, etc since no string comparison is being used.

Comment: @Remy - Thank you for the suggestion. I updated the answer accordingly. Used `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` instead of `SHCreateShellItem` though since Delphi 2007 has no knowledge of the latter..

Comment: @SerTac: you do not need to call `IShellItem.GetDisplayName()` or `StringToOleStr()`.  I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Remy! I noticed you've also nilled the IShellItem.