# How to determine if 2 paths reference the same file in portable C++

Tags: c++, reference, portability, filepath

I was wondering if there is a **portable** way to determine if 2 different paths actually reference the same file.

I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562701/best-way-to-determine-if-two-path-reference-to-same-file-in-c-c) but is Windows-specific.

AFAIK, *fstream* isn't suitable for the job.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way of determining that two file paths are referring to the same file object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497131/what-is-the-best-way-of-determining-that-two-file-paths-are-referring-to-the-sam)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Filesystem library**

Since C++17 you can use the standard [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) library. The function you are looking for is `equivalent`, under namespace `std::filesystem`:

```
bool std::filesystem::equivalent(const std::filesystem::path& p1, const filesystem::path& p2 );
```

To summarize from the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/equivalent): this function takes two paths as parameters and returns `true` if they reference the same file or directory, `false` otherwise. There is also a `noexcept` overload that takes a third parameter: an `std::error_code` in which to save any possible error.

For more information take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50320215/9481500) on the [thread you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562701/best-way-to-determine-if-two-path-reference-to-same-file-in-c-c).

Comment: I need a clarification though: why is the accepted answer ok? It seems to me basically the same as my old one: a link alone...

Comment: @Stypox: It has the same problem as your old. Thanks for Editing this!

Comment: Given that both paths already exist in the filesystem. To check if two paths before creation would potentially collide is a little more challenging.