# What is the best way of determining that two file paths are referring to the same file object?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

I want to write a unit test that checks that two file paths are equivalent, but I don't want to assume that the string representation is the same.

For example, on Linux there could be symlinks in the path in one case and not in the other. On Windows, there could be drive notation on one (`X:\foo`) and network notation on the other (`//serverX/foo`). And most complicated, the file may have been written on Linux on an [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_%28protocol%29) share (in `/path/to/file` syntax) and verified on Windows using DOS syntax (`X:\to\file`) where `X:` is a NFS mount to `/path`.

Some ideas (found here on Stack Overflow, but not unified):

1. On Linux, compare the inode from [`stat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650488/determining-if-two-file-paths-point-to-same-file-under-linux-c)
2. Use [`realpath`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/realpath.html) (Is this Platform independent?)
3. On Windows, compare strings on `GetFullPathName`
4. On Windows, compare serial numbers and file index from [`GetFileInformationByHandle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562701/best-way-to-determine-if-two-path-reference-to-same-file-in-windows)

What would be the cross-platform best solution? I'm writing this in C++, but I can drop down to C obviously.

Comment: not sure if it addresses your problem, but did you take a look at Boost::Filesystem? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Comment: @JossefHarush that wouldn't tell you if you're looking at two different copies of the same file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could check out the [`Boost.Filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library. Specifically, there is a method [`equivalent`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#equivalent) that seems to do exactly what you are looking for:

```
using namespace boost::filesystem;

path p("/path/to/file/one");
path q("/sym_link/to/one");
assert(equivalent(p, q));
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.  For reference, the boost implementation uses inode comparisons on Linux and serial number/file index comparions on Windows.

Comment: This works only if both paths already exist, so if you want to check a possible collision before creation you have to some more work to do.

Answer (score 3):

### **Filesystem library**

Since C++17 you can use the standard [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) library. The function you are looking for is `equivalent`, under namespace `std::filesystem`:

```
bool std::filesystem::equivalent(const std::filesystem::path& p1, const filesystem::path& p2);
```

To summarize from the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/equivalent): this function takes two paths as parameters and returns true if they reference the same file or directory, false otherwise. There is also a `noexcept` overload that takes a third parameter: an `std::error_code` in which to save any possible error.

For more information take a look at [my complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50320215/9481500) to another stack overflow question.