# GetProcessImageFileName path translation

Tags: windows, process, path

i need to make a comparison between directory containing the image of some running process.
when i use GetProcessImageFileName() the function give me a path with something like "\Device\HarddiskVolume3...." (i'll call it DevPath), instead of "C:..."(i'll call it C_Path)
i need to make comparison with other C_Path style path, so i should translate in the other kind of path, is that possible?

since i don't really need the drive letter, if is too troublesome to make a correct path translation could i simply read only the part of char after the N° backslash? making somethinglike 
(Pseudocode)

```
if(  ReadAfter3Backslash(DevPath) == ReadAfter1Backslash(C_Path))...
```

now the second question is: the DevPath have everytime exactly 3 slash before starting with "normal" directory? if a full translation isn't viable will this work?

PS: i know that exist the function QueryFullProcessImageName() that can give the "C..." path style but i'v got a lot of problem with that function, it currently crash and is hard to make it portable to pre-vista OS. since this seemes to be a more difficult way to solve my problem i'm ignoring it until i have hope with translation solution.

Comment: 1° suggestion) never take in account "DevPath" path style
2°) is not about distinguish handle, i didn't even mentioned them (although they must be used)
3) same as 1)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/562773/886887 which should work just as well for device-based paths as for drive-letter-based paths.