# What is the right way to compare two filenames to see if they are the same file?

Tags: c#, .net, comparison, filenames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to determine if two path reference to same file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410705/best-way-to-determine-if-two-path-reference-to-same-file-in-c-sharp)

So I have two Windows filenames I need to compare to determine if they are the same.  One the user gave me, one given to me by another program.  So how *should* you compare:

```
C:\Program Files\Application1\APP.EXE
C:\Progra~1\Applic~1\APP.EXE
C:\program files\applic~1\app.exe
```

I can't seem to find a way to consistently 'normalize' the path, I tried using Path.GetFullPath(path) and new FileInfo(path).FullName and neither seem to resolve this.

UPDATE:

Path.GetFullPath(path) will correct the short to long name conversion but it will not normalize case.  Thus a StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(path1, path2) is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need `Path.GetFullPath()` + case insensitive string comparison.

Running the following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test {
 static void Main ()
 {
  //string [] str = new string[] {@"c:\program files\vim\vim72", @"c:\progra~1\vim\vim72"};
  string [] str = new string[] {@"c:\program files\Refere~1\microsoft", @"c:\progra~1\Refere~1\microsoft"};
  foreach (string s in str) {
   // Call s = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables (s) if needed.
   Console.WriteLine (Path.GetFullPath (s));
  }
 }
}
```

gives:

```
c:\program files\Reference Assemblies\microsoft
c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\microsoft
```

Comment: Delete this quick, before you get hammered on the downvote...

Comment: It works for me here. I tried c:\Progra~1\Refere~1\Microsoft and c:\Program Files\Referenced Assemblies\microsoft...

Comment: Apparently he tried it.  I posted the same thing and got 3 downvotes instantly.

Comment: I added my test and its output to  the answer, just in case. Thanks.

Comment: @xaero You posted basically "try GetFullPath" when the question says "I tried GetFullPath".  Gonzalo included the necessary case-insensitive comparison, which is likely why it didn't work for the OP, and example code.

Comment: It's worth noting that `Path.GetFullPath` does not expand variables, so e.g., comparing `%PROGRAMFILES%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft` to `c:\program files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft` will not work.

Comment: Easy fix. Let me add a note to the answer...

Comment: @Tim - fair enough.  It's OK anyway, I got a badge for deleting my post... ;)

Comment: Also, I haven't tried it, but `GetFullPath` probably doesn't handle the junctions or links supported by recent versions of NTFS. Probably not an issue for 99.9% of people, though.

Comment: Yes, I thought about junctions and symbolic links in unix but didn't think it was worth mentioning.

Comment: I use them fairly often but that's definitely not common, you basically have to use non-MS software to do it outside the command line, e.g.: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html

Comment: This is the monster method that GetFullPath calls: http://paste-it.net/public/haa0ee9/

Comment: @Tim: in unix it would be readlink() and is part of the system C library.

Comment: This is working for my limited case... The answers involving GetFileInformationByHandle are just too complex to deal with.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

a short test run says that the below code will work for the paths given:

```
bool CompareFileName(string file1, string file2)
        {
            var directory1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(file1);
            var directory2 = Path.GetDirectoryName(file2);
            var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(file1);
            var fileName2 = Path.GetFileName(file2);

            return directory1.Equals(directory2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                   fileName1.Equals(fileName2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
```

this assumes windows platform (an assumption made due to the windows centric paths given as example paths)

Answer (score 0):

I use the FileInfo object. If you create a fileinfo object of a file that actually exists the Directory property gives a nicely formatted path name.

You also get the additional benefit of being able to test if the file actually exists.