# Problem with C# serialization extension methods

Tags: c#, serialization, extension-methods

I really like the extension method that TWith2Sugars posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/post-your-extension-goodies-for-c-net-codeplexcomextensionoverflow#271423).  I ran into an odd problem though.  When I put this into a shared class library and call the serialization function, I get the following error:

> The type MyType was not expected. Use
>   the XmlInclude or SoapInclude
>   attribute to specify types that are
>   not known statically.

I looked around a bit and found that the XmlSerializer can only serialize types that it is aware of.  I interpret this to mean classes that are in the class library, not the project that I build based off that libary.

Is there a way around this?  Can this function be placed into a class library or does it need to be in each project that uses it?

**Update:**

I figured out what was causing the problem.  I had the following code:

```
object o = new MyClass();
o.Serialize();
```

This was causing the error.  When I changed the code to:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.Serialize();
```

Everything ran fine.  So, lesson learned - don't try to (de)serialize generic objects.  The thing I liked the most about the link I referenced was that I did not have to put any XML attribute tags on my classes.  The extension method just worked.

For purposes of closing out the question, I will award the answer to whoever expands on [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515940/problem-with-c-serialization-extension-methods/515986#515986) (including Marc) with a code sample illustrating the use of [XmlInclude].

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is wrong. What this error means is basically as follows: XML serializer cannot operate on class hierarchies unless you explicitly tell it what classes are there in the said hierarchy. Just add `XmlInclude` attribute for the type of each derived class to your base class and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this source by adding a reference to the second assembly and using `[XmlInclude]` - but this might quickly get you into a circular mess of projects. You can also specify these options at runtime, into the serializer's constructor:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
[Serializable] public class Foo { }
[Serializable] public class Bar : Foo {}

static class Program {
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo),
            new Type[] { typeof(Bar) });
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, new Bar());
    }
}
```

Re the extension method; you could add a `params Type[] extraTypes`, and pass `extraTypes` into the `XmlSerializer` - then you can use it either as you do now, or as `.Serialize(typeof(Bar))`.

Comment: The problem I am having is that the failure is occurring when trying to serialize Foo.  Passing an extraType of object still gives the same error.