# Use of "this" keyword in formal parameters for static methods in C#

Tags: c#, parameters, this

I've come across several instances of C# code like the following:

```
public static int Foo(this MyClass arg)
```

I haven't been able to find an explanation of what the `this` keyword means in this case. Any insights?

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, for C# Extension Methods one must check out official [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: Extension methods are convenient but we must use caution when creating/using them - they can break! Quote from the General Guidelines in the [official MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx): "In general, we recommend that you implement extension methods sparingly and only when you have to. ... When using an extension method to extend a type whose source code you cannot change, you run the risk that a change in the implementation of the type will cause your extension method to break."

Comment: Does that mean [this](https://pastebin.com/j3i209Dx) would be possible? Because that's what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 344, accepted):

This is an **extension method**. See here for an [explanation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/13/new-orcas-language-feature-extension-methods.aspx).

> Extension methods allow developers to add new methods to the public
>   contract of an existing CLR type, without having to sub-class it or
>   recompile the original type.  Extension Methods help blend the
>   flexibility of "duck typing" support popular within dynamic languages
>   today with the performance and compile-time validation of
>   strongly-typed languages.
>
> Extension Methods enable a variety of useful scenarios, and help make
>   possible the really powerful LINQ query framework... .

it means that you can call

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
int i = myClass.Foo();
```

rather than

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
int i = Foo(myClass);
```

This allows the construction of [fluent interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) as stated below.

Comment: sub-classing is hard

Comment: @Gerry - what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, a little sarcasm - a lot of syntax these days seem to solve problems I didn't even know were problems. Readability should be a very high priority.

Comment: To be honest @Gerry, it kind of sounds like you're in a classic [Blub Paradox](https://wiki.c2.com/?BlubParadox). A lot of syntax these days solves problems you're not having because you didn't know there was a better way, or you're not doing the kind of task that this syntax is awesome for.

Most comments about '_this is a solution in search of a problem_' are actually an example of '_I don't know how that feature works, so it must be useless_'.

Answer (score 98):

[Scott Gu's quoted blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/13/new-orcas-language-feature-extension-methods.aspx) explains it nicely.

For me, the answer to the question is in the following statement in that post:

> Note how the static method above has a
>   "this" keyword before the first
>   parameter argument of type string. 
>   This tells the compiler that this
>   particular Extension Method should be
>   added to objects of type "string". 
>   Within the IsValidEmailAddress()
>   method implementation I can then
>   access all of the public
>   properties/methods/events of the
>   actual string instance that the method
>   is being called on, and return
>   true/false depending on whether it is
>   a valid email or not.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's the only answer that actually explains what the actual purpose of the `this` keyword in the method signature is. The other answers only unhelpfully say "it's an extension method." I never fully understood how extension methods "attach" to the types they extend until reading this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Wouldn't it be convenient if you could neatly pop a List<>, that is, not only remove the first element, but return it aswell?

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

**Without extension methods:**

```
public static class ContainerHelper
{
    public static T PopList<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        T currentFirst = list[0];
        list.RemoveAt(0);
        return currentFirst;
    }
}
```

Calling this method:

```
int poppedItem = ContainerHelper.PopList(myList);
```

**With extension methods:**

```
public static class ContainerHelper
{
    public static T PopList<T>(this List<T> list)//Note the addition of 'this'
    {
        T currentFirst = list[0];
        list.RemoveAt(0);
        return currentFirst;
    }
}
```

Calling this method:

```
int poppedItem = myList.PopList();
```

Comment: This example pairs nicely with [@JamesWiseman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376643/7232335).

Answer (score 12):

<sup>[In addition to Preet Sangha's explanation:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/846773)</sup>
Intellisense displays the extension methods with a blue arrow (e.g. in front of "Aggregate<>"):

[image]

You need a

```
using the.namespace.of.the.static.class.with.the.extension.methods;
```

for the extension methods to appear and to be available, if they are in a different namespace than the code using them.

Answer (score 7):

They are [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).  Welcome to a whole new [fluent world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/post-your-extension-goodies-for-c-net-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow). :)

Answer (score 5):

I just learnt this myself the other day: the this keyword defines that method has being an extension of the class that proceeds it. So for your example, MyClass will have a new extension method called Foo (which doesn't accept any parameter and returns an int; it can be used as with any other public method).

Answer (score 1):

"this" extends the next class in the parameter list

So in the method signature below "this" extends "String".  Line is passed to the function as a normal argument to the method.
public static string[] SplitCsvLine(this String line)

In the above example "this" class is extending the built in "String" class.

Answer (score -1):

The usage of modifier this before a parameter, is about extension method.

For more detailed explanation and example, see my CSDN blog.

http://t.csdn.cn/QYeW6

Comment: Good practices is to share next to a link, also the content / summary. A external link can be changed or can be deleted.