# What does the this keyword in a method declaration mean?

Tags: c#, .net, methods

I found a method declared like this:

```
public static int WordCount(this string str)
{
    return str.Length;
}
```

What's the `this` keyword in this particular context?

Comment: This must be a duplicate.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen [It is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846766/use-of-this-keyword-in-formal-parameters-for-static-methods-in-c-sharp).

Comment: [search for question](https://www.google.ca/search?q=What+does+the+this+keyword+in+a+method+declaration+mean%3F&oq=What+does+the+this+keyword+in+a+method+declaration+mean%3F&aqs=chrome.0.69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) title and go to the first link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). Extension methods allow you to extend a type. It's great for types like `string` for which you don't have access to the source code.

With the example you provided, instead of calling

```
string test = "foo";
var result = StaticClass.WordCount(test);
```

You could use it as follows:

```
string test = "foo";
var result = test.WordCount();
```

Trivia: LINQ is implemented using extension methods, and in fact was the primary reason extension methods were added to the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

It makes it an extension method.

What this means is that you can call the method like this:

```
arg.WordCount();
```

instead of like this:

```
Class.WordCount(arg);
```

It's mainly used for extending types (hence the name) that you can't directly modify the source code of.