# How do I invoke a Delegate faster than by using DynamicInvoke?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, delegates

Currently I use`DynamicInvoke`which is very slow. Still using the`Delegate`type how can I directly invoke the `Delegate` without late-binding/the`DynamicInvoke`?

```
Delegate _method;    
_method.DynamicInvoke(_args);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932699/what-is-the-difference-between-calling-a-delegate-directly-using-dynamicinvoke/932862#932862) answer to a similar question.

Comment: Thar post uses Action not Delegate. Not sure why Delegate doesn't have the same methods as Action.

Comment: Post real code.  It is quite unclear why you need to use Delegate instead of a declared delegate type.

Comment: It's been a few years, but you can nowadays cast the `Delegate` to a declared delegate type, provided you know the param and return types beforehand. This creates near-native performance by using the `Invoke` method on the typed delegate (on my system 5-10% slower than direct call).

Answer (score 4):

The open source framework [Impromptu-Inteface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) adds an extension method to `Delegate` called `FastDynamicInvoke` that runs a little over 20 times faster than `DynamicInvoke` by using the DLR instead of reflection.

```
using ImpromptuInterface
```

...

```
_method.FastDynamicInvoke(_args);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as calling `((dynamic)_method)(_args)`?

Comment: No because that wouldn't resolve unless `_method`'s signature takes an array.

Comment: @jbtule do you have example comprasion code? I tried it today and i founded slower

Comment: @Maya here is the Comparison Code: http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/source/browse/UnitTestImpromptuInterface/SpeedTest.cs#613

Comment: @jbtule thanks! Actually i saw already that it is faster but anyway thanks for the link. If you  are the lib developer thanks also for the excellent lib.

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke` is faster, but it's a bit "hidden".  From [MSDN on Delegate class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y22acf51.aspx)

> The common language runtime provides
>   an Invoke method for each delegate
>   type, with the same signature as the
>   delegate. You do not have to call this
>   method explicitly from C#, Visual
>   Basic, or Visual C++, because the
>   compilers call it automatically. The
>   Invoke method is useful in reflection
>   when you want to find the signature of
>   the delegate type.

What this means is that when you create a delegate type, the `Invoke` member is added with the correct signature by the compiler.  This allows calling without going through `DynamicInvoke`

In c#, you use this like:

```
_method(_args);
//or
_method(typedArg1, typedArg2, andSoOn);
```

calling it as you would a normal method.  This actually calls `Invoke`, which should be much faster for you.

Comment: Hrmmm I can't change the code to _method(_args);. I get a compiler error 'Method, delegate or event is expected'

Comment: Is your delegate actually just a "Delegate"?  or are you using a declared signature for it?

Comment: It's a System.Delegate. Thanks

Comment: Ahh, sorry - Then that makes sense.  If you are using only `System.Delegate` as the delegate type, then no `Invoke` method will be generated.  If you can create a specific delegate, you will see huge speed improvements.  However, with just a `Delegate`, this is not possible - every invocation will be a dynamic one.  I would suggest looking at c# 4 and the `dynamic` type if you really need to go this route as the DLR has some speed improvements.