# C# - passing a function of unknown type to another function and calling it

Tags: c#, generic-programming

In my program i'm suppose to get a function as a parameter, and call it from within another function. can it be done? 
thank you

Comment: Parametes, return type, ... ?

Comment: If you don't know function's parameters, you will hardly be able to pass any meaningful parameters at runtime and utilize the return value. You *can* use `DynamicInvoke` like [Jason explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068991/c-passing-a-function-of-unknown-type-to-another-function-and-calling-it/7069056#7069056), but his example again presumes that the delegate signature matches that of a plain `Action` delegate. If it doesn't, that code will fail at **runtime** (which is a bad thing). Are you sure that your method cannot be expressed using `Func<>` or `Action<>` generic delegates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you could just take in a [`Delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y22acf51.aspx) and utilize [`Delegate.DynamicInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx) or [`Delegate.Method.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ttck9d7.aspx). Barring more information, this answers your question.

Thus:

```
class Foo {
    public void M(Delegate d) {
        d.DynamicInvoke();
    }
}

Action action = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
var foo = new Foo();
foo.M(action);
```

Comment: I believe calling a delegate without parameters using DynamicInvoke is an overkill, why are you need late bound call? This is cost some performance. Here is the comparision of Invoke vs DynamicInvoke. Invoke x700 times faster, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932699/what-is-the-difference-between-calling-a-delegate-directly-using-dynamicinvoke/932862#932862

Comment: @sllev: There is no `Invoke` on `Delegate`, so it's not an option here. `Invoke` is only available for strongly-typed delegate types. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: d.DynamicInvoke() I beliebe this is a DynamicInvoke call on a delegate? Really this is still not clear for me

Comment: @sllev: That post you linked to compares the performance of `DynamicInvoke` to `Invoke` on a delegate. The issue is that `DynamicInvoke` is slower because it has to do parameter checking. The larger issue is that `Invoke` only exists for strongly-typed delegates and this gets at the reason that `Invoke` is faster: the compiler already takes care of all the parameter checking at compile time that `DynamicInvoke` has to do at runtime. This is why `Invoke` can only exist for strongly-typed delegates: it incorporates information from the type of the delegate into the signature for `Invoke`.

Comment: I understand the difference but not understan why you are used it your example, basically Invoke won't work in such case?

Comment: @sllev: As I said in my first comment, there is no method named `Invoke` on `Delegate`. The only possibility when you have a delegate but it is not strongly-typed is to use `DynamicInvoke`.

Comment: Now is clear. I've proposed to use Action and it has the Invoke() method, perhaps this is confused me

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

or you can use lambda expressions. delegate still, but faster to code.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NoReturnValue((i) =>
        {
            // work here...
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        });
    var value = ReturnSometing((i) =>
        {
            // work here...
            return i > 0;
        });
}

private static void NoReturnValue(Action<int> foo)
{
    // work here to determind input to foo
    foo(0);
}

private static T ReturnSometing<T>(Func<int, T> foo)
{
    // work here to determind input to foo
    return foo(0);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

An example:

```
Action logEntrance = () => Debug.WriteLine("Entered");
UpdateUserAccount(logEntrance);

public void UpdateUserAccount(
           IUserAccount account, 
           Action logEntrance)
{
   if (logEntrance != null)
   {
      logEntrance();
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

- Use `Func` to use arbitrary functions while preserving type safety.

  This can be done with the built-in Func generic class:

  Given a method with the following signature (in this case, it takes an int and returns a  bool):

  ```
  void Foo(Func<int, bool> fun);
  ```

  You can call it like this:

  ```
  Foo(myMethod);    
  Foo(x => x > 5);
  ```

  You can assign arbitrary functions to a Func instance:

  ```
  var f = new Func<int, int, double>((x,y) => { return x/y; });
  ```

  And you can pass that `f` around where it can be used later:

  ```
  Assert.AreEqual(2.0, f(6,3));  // ;-) I wonder if that works
  ```

  See [here](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Languages/Programming-with-Generic-Delegates-and-Lambda-Expressions/) for more information.
- Use Reflection when you really don't know the parameters, but you are willing to pay the cost to investigate them at run time.

  Read about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  You will be passing around instances of `MemberInfo`.  You can query its parameters to dynamically discover their number and type.
- use `dynamic` for complete freedom.  There is no type safety.

  And in C# 4.0, you now have the `dynamic` keyword.

  ```
  public void foo(dynamic f) {
    f.Hello();
  }

  public class Foo {
    public void Hello() { Console.WriteLine("Hello World");}
  }

  [Test]
  public void TestDynamic() {
    dynamic d = new Foo();
    foo(d);
  }
  ```

  See more on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx).

Comment: @Jason Reflection can handle functions of any type with any number of parameters.  But this is probably not what the asker meant -- Check the tags he used when asking the question.  And besides, if the type is unknown, why would you assume in your answer that that means 0 arguments?

Comment: Please remove your downvote -- completely unwarranted considering your lack of information of what the asker is searching for.

Comment: I know it's of unknown type. Therefore a strongly-typed solution like `Func` can not, Not, NOT work. When I downvoted you, that was the sole content of your answer. `dynamic` doesn't help because, at least based on your source code example, you're not receiving a delegate, but rather an object an invoking a method of known name on that object. That is not what the question asked for.