# Call a method in class from an external dll

Tags: c#, dll

so I'm looking for a way to call a method in an application externally from a dll. (see example below) This is what I'm trying however it's a) not working and b) if it was working i have a feeling that calling DynamicInvoke is going to be painfully slow.

first all if I did want to do it this way how do I deal with returns types as currently this will errors saying callthisexternally() has wrong return type.

is there a better way to do this?

```
--- within a a dll ---
public class mydll
{
    // etc.. blah blah
    public object callfromdll(string commandName, int requiredArgs, Delegate method)
    {
        // do stuff
        // now invoke the method
        return method.DynamicInvoke(method.Method.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
    }
}
-- within an application that's refrancing the above dll --
public someclass
{
    // etc.. stuff here
    mydll m = new mydll();
    m.callfromdll("callthisexternally", 0, new Action(callthisexternally));
    // the function to be called externally
    public string callthisexternally()
    {
        // do stuff
        return "i was called!";
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to provide more details about `callfromdll` as right now it does not make sense why you are doing it this way instead of just passing a [`Func` delegate in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx)

Comment: Probably not the entire answer but `new Action(callthisexternally)` will not work because `callthisexternally` returns a value.  You should use `new Func<string>(callthisexternally)`

Comment: @DStanley refresh, I updated my comment already.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think your missing the point here, that code was just something i typed up off the top of my head as I'm spitballing ideas on how to do this. Hence the question "is there a better way to do this" as in, is there some kind of standard for this.

Comment: Without knowing WHY you need the delegate, its hard to say what you should do. I posted a answer showing how to pass in a function that returns a result.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details of what callFromDll is supposed to do you can do this simply with a [Func Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx)

```
public class mydll
{
    // etc.. blah blah
    public T callfromdll<T>(string commandName, int requiredArgs, Func<T> method)
    {
        // do stuff
        // now invoke the method
        return method();
    }
}
```

If your `do stuff` was doing something to generate a `int` you just need to use the correct method siginature.

```
public class mydll
{
    // etc.. blah blah
    public T callfromdll<T>(string commandName, int requiredArgs, Func<int, T> method)
    {
        int x = SomeComplexFunction(commandName, requiredArgs);
        return method(x);
    }
}
-- within an application that's refrancing the above dll --
public someclass
{
    public void test()
    {
        // etc.. stuff here
        mydll m = new mydll();
        var result = m.callfromdll("callthisexternally", 0, new Func(callthisexternally));
        //result contains "i was called, and my result was #" and where # is replace with the number passed in to callthisexternally
    }

    // the function to be called externally
    public string callthisexternally(int x)
    {
        // do stuff
        return "i was called, and my result was " + x;
    }
}
```

Now your DLL will pass in the value it calculated for x in to the function you passed in and it will give you the result from that function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add that using DynamicInvoke is, as you suspected, very slow and should be avoided if possible:
[What is the difference between calling a delegate directly, using DynamicInvoke, and using DynamicInvokeImpl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932699/what-is-the-difference-between-calling-a-delegate-directly-using-dynamicinvoke)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what your trying to do here, maybe your new to C# so.

Do you try to reference a dll that you didnt wrote?, its ok just add a reference to the dll in your project. If written also in c# it usually works.
Remind that there are tons of dll's as part of SDK's that can be included that way to suit your project. Here a video to explain it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmz_K9iLGU8

If you like to execute another program externally

```
using System.Diagnostics;
class Program
 {
  static void Main()
   {
    // Use Process.Start here.
    Process.Start("C:\\HitchHickersGuide.exe /Towl /42");
   }
 }
```