# Useful extension methods C# library for the Date object

Tags: c#, extension-methods, date

Could you guys recommend me a library which handles the most common missing features for the `Date` object in C#?

.. Things like figuring out:

- What quarter a given date is in
- Get the start/end of a given quarter/month/week
- Various subtraction -and addition methods

**Note:** A library which implements its features as extension methods would be a plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some interesting datetime extension methods (especially for addition/subtraction) in this post: [Post your extension goodies for C# .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/post-your-extension-goodies-for-c-net-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow).
Check in particular the first answer for datetime-based extension libraries. The methods are being collected in a CodePlex project, maybe it's worth having a look.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt on extension methods for DateTime type. You can download it from sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/projects/xtensionsuite/

Also I have provided the list of methods so far I have added in this suite, and some examples in my blog. http://lazypro.nallenthal.in/ganesh-periasamy/english/coding/xtensionsuite-1/

hope this will help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used it myself, but Jon Skeet is behind [Noda Time](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/), library designed to manage C# dates and times easier. Noda Time is based on [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). Dedicated [Noda Time blog](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/) can provide valuable insights.