# C# Problem encrypting using RSA

Tags: c#, rsa

I am using this function which I pulled off MSDN

```
static public byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] DataToEncrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] encryptedData;
                //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
                using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
                {

                    //Import the RSA Key information. This only needs
                    //toinclude the public key information.
                    RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

                    //Encrypt the passed byte array and specify OAEP padding.  
                    //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or
                    //later.  
                    encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
                }
                return encryptedData;
            }
            //Catch and display a CryptographicException  
            //to the console.
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                return null;
            }

        }
```

I am calling the method from here:

```
 using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {

                //Pass the data to ENCRYPT, the public key information 
                //(using RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(false),
                //and a boolean flag specifying no OAEP padding.
                encryptedData = RSAEncrypt(dataToEncrypt, RSA.ExportParameters(false), false);
```

But I am getting this error message:

```
Key not valid for use in specified state.
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine!! I tried it, I think you may have a problem in decryption as you should use the same keys

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i have no idea about your Rsa problem but you may want to try this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/post-your-extension-goodies-for-c-net-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow) , which i use for a long time.

```
public static string Encrypt(this string stringToEncrypt, string key)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToEncrypt))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("An empty string value cannot be encrypted.");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Cannot encrypt using an empty key. Please supply an encryption key.");
            }

            System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters cspp = new System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters();
            cspp.KeyContainerName = key;

            System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspp);
            rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = true;

            byte[] bytes = rsa.Encrypt(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt), true);

            return BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
        }
```

You can also find Decrypt Extension there. I hope it'll help.