# or condition in if condition

Tags: c#

i have  condition need  to  be  check

```
if(staffid!=23||staffid!=24||staffid!=25||staffid!=26||staffid!=27||staffid!=29||staffid!=31)
{
  do the  req  thing ..
}
```

right now  i    checking the  condition like   this . 
is their  any better  way  to  write this  condition

thank  you

Comment: You mean && instead of || right?

Comment: I'm sure you mean && instead of ||. By DeMorgan's Law, Not P or Not Q = Not (P and Q). Now, assuming staffid cannot be 23 and 24 simultaneously, Not (P and Q) will always evaluate to true. (PS - I made this silly mistake the first day of my current internship :P )

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Merging several of the other answers (mjv, pasta, Mike Hofer, R. Bemrose) together you will come up with the following code.

1. Use a function to test if the staff ID is valid, that way you only need to change one place.
2. An int array doesn't have a Contains method, so you will need to convert it to an IList (Unless using the extension methods provided in 3.0 in the System.Linq namespace).

As for the code:

```
if(!isStaffIDValid(staffid))
{
    //do the req thing ..
}
```

...

Then in either the same class, or more preferably a global class use this code:

```
public static IList<int> notAllowedIDs = new int[] { 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 31 };
public static bool isStaffIDValid(int staffID)
{
    return !notAllowedIDs.Contains(staffID);
}
```

This provides more maintainable code that can be easily updated.

Comment: btw, you're missing a close parens.

Comment: Could use a `HashSet<int>`: `private static HashSet<int> excluded = new HashSet<int>(new [] { ... });` then `return !excluded.Contains(id)`.

Comment: If there are a lot of IDs, `HashSet` will be faster.  If there are not, HashSet may or may not be faster, but it is probably irrelevant anyways..

Comment: yes you can use .Contains (if youre on 3.0 i think) it's an extension method on System.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 19):

Errr.. isn't that equivalent to:

```
if (true) { do the req thing... }
```

Unless `staffid` can simultaneously be 23 and 24 and 25 and 26 and 27 and 29 and 31.

Imagine 2 cases:

1. `staffid = 23`
2. `staffid != 23`

Your statement:

```
if(staffid!=23 ||
   staffid!=24 ||
   staffid!=25 ||
   staffid!=26 ||
   staffid!=27 ||
   staffid!=29 ||
   staffid!=31)
{
  do the  req  thing ..
}
```

Case 1 passes the second test (`staffid != 24`), and case 2 passes the first test (`staffid!=23`). Since case 1 and case 2 together account for all cases, all values of `staffid` should pass your test.

Comment: I don't think this is what he was intending. ;)

Comment: @Chris - neither do I, but I thought it was probably more worthwhile to point out his code was broken, than to guess at what he did intend.

Comment: Although, the title of the question specifically mentions `or`, so I reckon bets are off as to what he's trying to do!

Comment: This is not even programming, then: it is simple classical logic.

Answer (score 7):

Can't imagine what your actual problem is, the statement looks wrong.

If there are lots of "not"s in a complex condition, just convert it to say the contrary. If there is both a if and else section, swap them. If there is no else, put the "not" to the beginning. Your condition looks wrong, just to show what I mean, here is the converted one:

```
if (staffid == 23 
  && staffid == 24
  && staffid == 25
  && staffid == 26
  && staffid == 27
  && staffid == 29
  && staffid == 31)
{
  //if there was an else block before, it will be here now.
}
else
{
  //do the  req  thing ..
}
```

Then you can more easily understand the condition, and more easily see that it can't be what you need...

Comment: +1, De Morgans for the win!  Also it more easily shows the mistake in the logic.

Answer (score 3):

Use a function allowStaff(staffid, "Payment"). Then have all your checking done in one central function allowStaff. This way even if you get a clever idea, you can change it in one place and quicker!

Answer (score 3):

First, what is the *data type* of `staffid`? Is it an `enum`? An `int`?

Then, the variable's name is sending up a red flag to me. Are you hard-coding behavior for specific individuals or roles into your application when those behaviors/roles may change down the road? You may want to rethink that.

Now, that out of the way, and assuming that `staffid` is an `int`:

```
int[] inValidIds = {23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 31};
if (! ((IList<int>)inValidIds.Contains(staffId)))
{
    // Do stuff;
}
```

See [here](http://www.dotnettoad.com/index.php?/archives/10-Array.Contains.html).

Comment: hi mike the  data type i am using is  int  for  checking the  staffid    once  if  id is  present i  sending the  return value as  false  from  my validation  layer  to      bussineess layer
 so onc ethe value is  present means  i need  to  send   the  return value as   false

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean:

```
    if (staffid != 23 && staffid != 24 && staffid != 25 && staffid != 26 && staffid != 27 && staffid != 29 && staffid != 31)
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
```

Saw a nice extension method to do this:

```
public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
{
  if(null==source) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  return list.Contains(source);
}
```

so your code would be:

```
if(!staffid.In(23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 31))
{
  do the  req  thing ..
}
```

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/post-your-extension-goodies-for-c-net-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow/833477#833477)

Comment: hi JDunkerley,
 your   code  worked   for me   perfect
 thank  you

Answer (score 2):

I think Chris is on the right track here, but why convert to a list?

```
public static int[] notAllowedIDs = new int[] { 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 31 };

// Other code here

if (Array.IndexOf(notAllowedIDs, staffId) < 0)
{
    // do the  req  thing ..
}
```

Additional notes: `Array.IndexOf` and `List.Contains` are both O(*n*) operations, where n is the number of elements.  However, `Array.IndexOf` saves a conversion from an array to a list.

`Array.IndexOf` returns the array's lower bound - 1 when the element isn't found, which is -1 for most arrays.

Comment: `Array` extends the `IList`.  The `.Contains` method is actually from the `IList` interface.  Polymorphism!  But good point.  I modified my answer to incorporate this suggestion. +1

Comment: @Chris: I usually deal with Java, so arrays implementing IList seems... odd to me.

Comment: Wait, I misspoke...  while *`Array` does extend `IList`*, it does not provide an implementation to the `.Contains` method.  This is allowable because the `Array` class is declared as abstract.  So `Array.Contains` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

How about just

```
if(staffid < 23 || staffid == 30 || staffid > 31)
{
    do the  req  thing ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: your logic is probably wrong. 
You can use a switch with cases that cascade, e.g.

```
switch(var)
{
   case foo:
   case bar:
      doIt();
      break;
}
```

Comment: @JeffH uh... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(VS.80).aspx So what do you mean by "Nope'?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe @JeffH meant:  the variables `foo` and `bar` can't be used in the `switch` statement unless they are `const`.  Also `var` is a reserved word in C# 3.0.

Comment: which needless to say your code isn't invalid if the variable are `const` and you and using c# 2.0.

Comment: Ah. I just left the syntax as an exercise for the OP :p

Answer (score 0):

Put your lists of staff id's in a List, and use LINQ to query a list of integers (if staffid not in list).

Comment: not a bad solution but kind of overkill for what he's trying to accomplish