# Extensions library in C#

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I am looking for a good Extensions library (library with a great number of extensions methods) in C# for standard type. I have found some libraries on [Codeplex](http://codeplex.com), but they are considered to be very weak by me.

**Edit:** I need a library which implements different mathematical functions for different (more the better) purposes.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What functionality in particular are you looking for?

Comment: You could always write your own.

Comment: If you are looking for a math library, then the fact that it contains lots of extension methods should be rather irrelevant...

Comment: @orsogufo, I have different math libraries, but I need math extensions library for simplification my work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the [Extension Overflow](http://www.codeplex.com/extensionoverflow) project on Codeplex, which was born from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/post-your-extension-goodies-for-c-net-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow).

Otherwise, if you are looking for a math library, have a look at [C# Programming Tools on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336818.aspx). I don't know if the math libraries there contain lots of extension methods, anyway...

Comment: I can't seem to download the extension overflow project. Has it been discontinued?

Comment: @The_Butcher: I cannot access codeplex at all... maybe it's temporary down?

Answer (score 3):

[MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) fills much of the gaps in the built-in extensions for LINQ-to-Objects. The project seems to be alive and maintained and is also available as a nuget package (BETA).

Answer (score 2):

Some good examples have been put together in [Extension overflow](http://www.codeplex.com/extensionoverflow)

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/post-your-extension-goodies-for-c-net-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you looking for such an extension library? It seems that you are missing some functionality in the framework you are not wanting to implement yourself.

If you want to get any useful answers you need to tell us what purpose the library should fulfill.

If you are missing some features in Linq, you can look at [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

Answer (score 0):

http://dnpextensions.codeplex.com/ is probably the more maintained library now.