# List operations getting a list's index

Tags: c#, windows-8, collections

I have a class in my Windows application like so:

```
public class Pets
{
  String Name {get;set;}
  int Amount {get;set;}
}
```

In one of my other classes i made a List of that class like so.

```
List<Pets> myPets = new List<Pets>();
myPets.Add(new Pets{ Name = "Fish", Amount = 8});
myPets.Add(new Pets{ Name = "Dogs", Amount = 2});
myPets.Add(new Pets{ Name = "Cats", Amount = 2});
```

Is there a way i can get the Index of the `Pets` whos `Name = "Fish"`?

I realize i can do this

```
int pos = 0;

for(int x = 0; x<myPets.Count;x++)
{
    if( myPets[x].Name == "Fish")
    {
        pos = x;
    }
}
```

But in the case that i have ALOT of items in `myPets` it would take long to loop through them to find the one i am looking for. Is there another way to complete the task above. That would make my application run quicker? In the case that `myPets` has a lot of items in it.

Comment: What is real task: to get index of element whose `Name = "Fish"` or to get element itself?

Comment: @nsinreal to get the index of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find index only to access item of List you can use Dictionary instead.

```
var pets = new Dictionary<string, int>();
pets.Add("Dogs", 2);
pets.Add("Fish", 8);
int amount = pets["Fish"];
```

Comment: @user2716979 Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class is implemented as a hash table. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: thnx alot. I  will use this.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have your data structured at the moment does not lend itself well to searching by pet's name if the list is large.

So iterating manually like you suggest and what `FindIndex` is doing is known as a [linear search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) which is a brute force algorithm. If you have N items in your collection, the worst case scenario to find an item is N iterations. This is known as O(N) using the Big O Notation. The speed of search grows linearly with the number of items within your collection.

For faster searching you need to change to a different data structure (like a Hashtable), use a database or implement a different search algorithm, such as a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)( `O(log(n)) complexity` ).

Have a look at this question for an example:
[Can LINQ use binary search when the collection is ordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766328/can-linq-use-binary-search-when-the-collection-is-ordered)