# Linq sort first two numbers in long type

Tags: c#, linq

I want to sort a list of members with respect to the first two digits of the property Civic Number.
If the search year is 82, everyone who has a Civic Number beginning with 82 are left in the list returned.

Here is a method I have written returns a sorted list with respect to first letters in a name.

```
private static List<Member> GetNameList(string searchString) 
{
    return _sortMemberList.Where(x => x.FirstName.ToLower().StartsWith(searchString.ToLower())).ToList();
}
```

I want to write a simular method but with regards on Civic Number. The Civic Number is 10 digits long and is of the data type "long". I know this doesn't work but well, here is something:

```
private static List<Member> GetMonthList(int searchYear)
{
    return _sortMemberList.OrderBy(x => x.CivicNumber > searchYear).ToList();
}
```

Best regards
Robert Jarlvik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest, very inefficient approach would simply be

```
_sortMemberList.Where(x => x.CivicNumber.ToString().StartsWith(searchYear.ToString())).ToList()
```

Otherwise, you could do

```
_sortMemberList.Where(x => (x.CivicNumber/100000000) == searchYear ).ToList()
```

assuming you know that all numbers are indeed 10 positions and `searchYear` is always 2 digits

If the list is *already* sorted, you can make it more efficient:

```
_sortMemberList
     .SkipWhile(x => x.CivicNumber < searchYear*100000000 )
     .TakeWhile(x => (x.CivicNumber/100000000) == searchYear )
     .ToList()
```

Even more efficient would be to use binary-search to locate the lowerbound of the target year, but that can only be done if `_sortMemberList` allows random access (indexing): see

- [Can LINQ use binary search when the collection is ordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766328/can-linq-use-binary-search-when-the-collection-is-ordered/1766369#1766369)
- or the [**`List<T>.BinarySearch`** Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6.aspx)

Comment: @Robert-Jarlvik: The only suggestion I would make would be to externalize your "get year from number" logic to a function, so you could do something like: `.SkipWhile(x => GetYear(x) < searchYear).TakeWhile(x => GetYear(x) == searchYear)`. It's more readable and more maintainable.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce that of course, a good point. I chose to shed some light on efficiency aspects instead.