# WPF- MEF UX binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mef

WPF newb here.
Consider the following situation

- Parent user control A
- Parent control has a placeholder / slot that
  these MEF extension User control can be loaded into dynamically.
- All MEF extensions that provide a User control implement a specific interface. This includes a boolean that they can set to indicate an operation is complete.
- Parent A has a button that needs to be enabled when the specific property(mentioned in the point above) is set to true.

Is this possible? If yes , how?

Is binding + INotifyPropertyChanged the way to go?

We've also thought of passing in Actions that can be used to update the state of the parent.

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Take a look at event aggregator pattern, also look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/30459296/1462656

Answer (score 0):

So let me explain;

1. if dynamically loaded user control has no data context (no view model is set), then user control uses view model of parent.
2. But if you define a view model for each user control, you can import these view models and manage them in parent view model.
3. Consider also using a BaseViewModel (BindableBase for MEF)