# Can I use null conditional operator instead of classic event raising pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, events, c#-6.0

C# 6.0 adds this new `?.` operator which now allows to invoke events like so:

```
someEvent?.Invoke(sender, args);
```

Now, from what I read, this operator guarantees that someEvent is evaluated once.
Is it correct to use this kind of invocation instead of the classic pattern:

```
var copy = someEvent

if(copy != null)
  copy(sender, args)
```

I'm aware of [certain scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2123826/1865984) where above version of pattern would require additional locks, but let's assume the simplest case.

Comment: Yes. And there's a blog post by Jon Skeet about doing just that.

Comment: It's actually a set of operators: `?.`, `?[`.

Comment: @Paulo Morgado, I did correct it in the question, however I've found in Linqpad5 syntax tree view, that it's single `?` that gets parsed as an operator token, the following `[0]` is parsed as `SingleMemberAccessExpression, or some other expression in case of `.` access.

Comment: @GrzegorzSławecki and that all forms a `ConditionalAccessExpression`, right? IT might be more of a philosophical discussion, but that's what the documentation for the language (not the compiler) says.

Comment: @Paulo Morgado, I agree that this is just a philosophical discussion and that's true that the documentation says that. I'm just wondering why. My reasoning is that if `?[` is an operator, then how would we call corresponding `]`.

Comment: @GrzegorzSławecki I think you are mixing operators with expressions. There is no mention of operators in the expression trees.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes

See [*Null-conditional Operators* on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).

There is an example covering what you ask

Without the null conditional operator

```
var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
if (handler != null)
    handler(…)
```

With the null conditional operator

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(e)
```

> The new way is thread-safe because the compiler generates code to evaluate PropertyChanged one time only, keeping the result in temporary variable.