# How to perform method overload resolution for types known at runtime?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, runtime, overloading

I have a class that contains method overloads :

```
public static void Foo(string a, string b)
public static void Foo(DateTime a, DateTime b)
public static void Foo<T>(ICollection<T> a, T b)
public static void Foo<T>(T a, ICollection<T> b)
public static void Foo<T>(ICollection<T> a, ICollection<T> b)
public static void Foo<T, U>(T a, U b) where T : IComparable
public static void Foo<T, U>(T a, U b)
```

I retrieve all methods at runtime this way :

```
var methods = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

**For two given parameter types (eg : `typeof(int)`, `typeof(List<int>)`) I would like to dynamically select the most appropriate method.**

What I tried/checked so far :

- `Binder.SelectMethod()` : generics are not supported by that method.
- `typeof().IsAssignableFrom()` : same as above. there is some support for generic parameters (eg : providing generic parameter `T` and its constraints against type `int` will be evaluated correctly) but not for generic type with arguments (eg : `List<int>` vs `List<>` or vs `List<T>` (this type would come from generic method and might `T` include some constraints))
- calling `MakeGenericMethod()` with input parameters for all generic methods, and catching the argument exceptions until there is none : ugly.
  And it probably will need some additional work to be done because types I would provide to `MakeGenericMethod()` might not be exactly the same as initial types I receive (eg : I have `typeof(List<int>), typeof(int)` while i should provide `typeof(int)` to `MakeGenericMethod()`.

I know this is a complex topic and no trivial problem but there is a few things that are fixed and should make things easier :

- all methods have two parameters and the same return type
- there is no optional types, no arrays.
- generic methods have one or two generic parameters no more, with parameters always in same order.
- covariance/contravariance does not need to be supported
- methods are already sorted by "priority". that is why the generic one without constraints is at the end of this list.
  once one method has match we can take it and ignore the other methods

**I would like to know if there is a way to do resolve these overloads using existing class/methods from C# Framework (without re-inventing the wheel) and if not possible what would be a possible solution (custom code)**

Answer (score 0):

Considering your described prerequisites, you can do this:

```
static void ExecuteCase(object a, object b)
{
    var method = GetMethod(typeof(Bar).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static), a.GetType(), b.GetType());
    if (method != null) { method.Invoke(null, new object[] {a, b}); }
    else { /* Handle method not found */ }
}
```

Where `GetMethod` is:

```
private static MethodInfo GetMethod(IEnumerable<MethodInfo> methods, Type typeA, Type typeB)
{
    foreach (var method in methods)
    {
        List<MethodInfo> candidates = new List<MethodInfo>();
        if (!method.IsGenericMethod) { candidates.Add(method); }
        else
        {
            MethodInfo genericMethod;
            if (IsParameterOfGeneric(typeA, typeB) && TryMakeGenericMethod(method, typeB, typeB, out genericMethod)) candidates.Add(genericMethod);
            if (IsParameterOfGeneric(typeB, typeA) && TryMakeGenericMethod(method, typeA, typeA, out genericMethod)) candidates.Add(genericMethod);
            if (typeA.IsGenericType && typeB.IsGenericType && TryMakeGenericMethod(method, typeA.GetGenericArguments()[0], typeB.GetGenericArguments()[0], out genericMethod)) candidates.Add(genericMethod);
            if (TryMakeGenericMethod(method, typeA, typeB, out genericMethod)) candidates.Add(genericMethod);
        }

        foreach (var candidate in candidates)
        {
            var args = candidate.GetParameters();
            if (args[0].ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(typeA) && args[1].ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(typeB)) return candidate;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private static bool IsParameterOfGeneric(Type generic, Type parameter)
{
    if (!generic.IsGenericType) return false;
    return generic.GetGenericArguments()[0] == parameter;
}

private static bool TryMakeGenericMethod(MethodInfo method, Type typeA, Type typeB, out MethodInfo genericMethod)
{
    genericMethod = null;
    try
    {
        genericMethod = method.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1
            ? method.MakeGenericMethod(typeA)
            : method.MakeGenericMethod(typeA, typeB);

        return true;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message.Contains("violates the constraint of type")) return false;
        throw;
    }
}
```

FYI, [why use try-catch on `TryMakeGenericMethod`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4864565/2355482)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Anyway the signature `ExecuteCase<T1, T2>` method is not good IMO, because it use generic arguments and it imply that I know input types as runtime (which I don't this this the whole point of the OP). Also : would that MakeGenericMethod try and catch technique works if, for example, input types are `List<int>, int` and the method to match is `Foo<T>(List<T> a, T b)` ? (then the generic argument should be just `int` not `List<int>` and `int`).

Comment: See edit. Fixed the issue with the case you mentioned in the comment above. Also changed `ExecuteCase` from generics to `object`.

Comment: I use a custom solution  which implementation is very similar to `IsAssignableFrom()` method from microsoft : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,ba0cffea035fe210

The difference is instead of checking directly types equality (eg : `this == c`) it used a custom method which take care of generics (eg : `typeof(List<int> == typeof(List<>)` will be true)

It works pretty good. I will post that solution (after cleaning) if I found some time.