# C# Reflection and overloaded Methods: Get Method the compiler would have chosen / "Closest Ancestor"

Tags: c#, reflection, polymorphism, overloading

Given this Situation:

```cs
class Wrapper {
   class Base {}
   class A : Base {}
   interface IA {}
   class B : A, IA {}

   void Func(Base param) {}
   void Func(A param) {}
   void Code() 
   {
      var param = new B();
      Func(param); //the compiler picks the "best polymorphism match" or maybe "closest ancestor", which is Func(A param)
   }
}
```

I don't actually know how the compiler picks the method. I assume it's the "closest ancestor", but I'm aware that this definition has problems itself - When a `void Func(IA param) { }` is added to the code above, the call `Func(param);` becomes a compile error `CS0121    The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Wrapper.Func(A)' and 'Wrapper.Func(IA)'`

With Reflection, how would I go about to find the same `Func` the compiler would have chosen if the Type information had been available at compile time?
`typeof([Func-param]).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(B))` is true for both function params. `typeof(B).IsSubclassOf([Func-param])` is also true for both functions.

This is however only part of the answer I'm looking for. What I actually have is a `List<Type>`, and I'd like to search the List for the "closest match" using the same rules as the compiler would when resolving the correct Func above.

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases like this, [`Type.GetMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=net-7.0) can basically do what you want.

```
var method = typeof(Wrapper)
    .GetMethod(
        "Func", 
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, 
        new Type[] { /* e.g. */ typeof(Wrapper.B) });
```

`method` will be assigned the `A` overload, and a `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException` will be thrown if you add in the `IA` overload.

If you want to read about the rules of overload resolution, [see the relevant section in the language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1264-overload-resolution).

If your methods are generic, and you need to do type inference, `GetMethod` won't work. You can check out [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384444/how-to-perform-method-overload-resolution-for-types-known-at-runtime) for some ideas though.