# Place for C# util libs?

Tags: c#, resources

Is there a place i could get C# util libs? I dont mean big libs or things like zlib. Something like a collection of helper functions like getting the most leftmost subdomain, fixing the /'s and \'s in a filename (i know its easy but still), writing the BOM for a textfile (maybe this exist but i dont know it), etc.

Comment: The Encoding classes contain the byte sequences for a BOM. And perhaps even a helper method to write it into a stream. Check the `GetPreamble` function

Comment: [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/), [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/), [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/), [Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/hosting/) ect...?

Comment: @digEmAll: Those are for projects and libs. I am talking more of a collection. CodeInChaos: Found it and an alternative.`new StreamWriter(fn, true, Encoding.UTF8);`

Comment: @acidzombie: Well, every site is basically a big collection of libs :P

Comment: about the filename, try 'System.IO.Path.Combine(...' or other method in this class

Comment: @Leo: alright i'll note it. I never actually had a problem with it, it was an example of the small things i want. The subdomain part is what i actually needed

Comment: URI URL classes in the to get the Host portion, then String.Split...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the "collection of helper functions", you might want to check this thread: [What are your favorite extension methods for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/what-are-your-favorite-extension-methods-for-c-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow)

It's basically a collection of small utilities, that have also been collected in the [ExtensionOverflow](http://extensionoverflow.codeplex.com/) CodePlex project.

There are several interesting things there. I don't know about the things you are asking explicitly, but it's surely worth a look...

Comment: Thats exactly what i am talking about. Good stuff