# Are there many free/open source extension methods libraries available?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I'm building my own libraries, but I'm wondering what's already available for extending string, numeric types, most importantly, IEnumerable. What am I missing out?

Comment: I will go play with Extension Overflow and .NET extension library. I'll let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [some on Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=extension%20methods&ac=8), including [Extension Overflow](http://extensionoverflow.codeplex.com/), which is based on the question, [What are your favorite extension methods for C#? (codeplex.com/extensionoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/post-your-extension-goodies-for-c-net) .

Comment: Nice! Did not find this one before asking because I did not use the word 'favorite', which is kind of discriminated in questions.

Answer (score 1):

CodePlex is a good place to look for this sort of thing, for example:

> [The .NET Extension Library](http://nxl.codeplex.com/)
>
> [The .NET Extension Library - Contents](http://nxl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=list%20of%20contents&referringTitle=Home)

This one is probably a bit out of date now given recent .NET 4.0 advances:

> [Wintellect's Power Collections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/)

Comment: This is nice, but kind of idle...