# An extension method on IEnumerable needed for shuffling

Tags: c#, ienumerable, shuffle

I need an extension method which will shuffle an `IEnumerable<T>`. It can also take an `int` to specify the size of the returned `IEnumerable`. Better keeping Immutability of the `IEnumerable`. My current solution for `IList`-

```
public static IList<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list, int size)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    var res = new T[size];

    res[0] = list[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        int j = rnd.Next(i);
        res[i] = res[j];
        res[j] = list[i];
    }
    return res;
}

public static IList<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
{ return list.Shuffle(list.Count); }
```

Comment: note that in order for `< >` to appear they generally *must* be formatted as code, either inline with backquotes (as I hvae added) or (as you have done) with four-space indentation

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use a [Fisher-Yates-Durstenfeld shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm). There's no need to explicitly pass a size argument to the method itself, you can simply tack on a call to [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) if you don't need the entire sequence:

```
var shuffled = originalSequence.Shuffle().Take(5);

// ...

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return source.Shuffle(new Random());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if (rng == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rng));

        return source.ShuffleIterator(rng);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> ShuffleIterator<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng)
    {
        var buffer = source.ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Count; i++)
        {
            int j = rng.Next(i, buffer.Count);
            yield return buffer[j];

            buffer[j] = buffer[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the purpose of 2nd method to just throw exception?

Comment: Yes, it's so that the argument checking is done eagerly rather than being deferred. If the second and third methods were rolled together then any argument checking wouldn't take place until you started iterating the sequence.

Comment: Luke, when you are calling source.ToList() in your main method, doesn't that imply the IEnumerable is executed (probably if its a Linq enumerable, then you are breaking their deferred execution? Better to ask for an IList!

Comment: @nawfal: Yes, the method has to buffer the contents of the source `IEnumerable<>` so that it can perform the shuffle. It then yields its *output* lazily. I'm not sure what you mean about asking for an `IList`, or how that would help.

Comment: @LukeH Let's assume `source` in your case is `var d = p.Select(...).OrderBy(...)`, when you do a ToList from inside the method, its executing the above query. If you are taking an `IList` instead as the parameter, the execution (by doing a `ToList` or `ToArray` for `d`) will have to be done from the caller side, so that gives no confusion about side effects of Shuffle method. I hope its clear

Comment: @nawfal: I see. Doing that would go against the LINQ philosophy of no side-effects. Taking an `IEnumerable<>` sequence and returning a new, shuffled sequence is preferable, imo, to taking an `IList<>` and mutating it.

Comment: @nawfal: It's easy enough to write a non-LINQy method to do that: something like `public static void ShuffleInPlace<T>(this IList<T> source)`

Comment: @LukeH I'm not saying shuffle should take place on the same enumerable. In fact it should return a new shuffled sequence. but since the shuffle method executes the possible query that is an `IEnumerable` `source`, its against the `Linq`'s deferred execution. So you may not get the best of Linq's lazy evaluation. I'm just saying if ever this Shuffle method is used with Linq, it behaves unlike all typical Linq methods. If you declare it IList, you are giving the caller the know-how of if the expression will be executed or not.

Comment: I'm not saying the above method is bad, but just that it may not be that good to be used along with Linq. Just thinking. I made it a [separate question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556837/is-it-safe-to-accept-ienumerablet-as-argument-after-the-introduction-of-linq) only to get down votes :)

Comment: @nawfal: Many built-in LINQ methods buffer-up the entire sequence internally and then yield results lazily: for example, `GroupBy`, `OrderBy`, `OrderByDescending`, `ThenBy`, `ThenByDescending`, `Reverse` etc all need to buffer their source sequence; `Except`, `GroupJoin`, `Intersect`, `Join` etc all buffer their "secondary" input sequence. It's not a problem, imo, although it is a good idea to clearly document whether or not a method needs to buffer the entire sequence internally.

Comment: No need for the second method to exist

Answer (score 1):

With some LINQ love:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int size)
{
    var r = new Random();
    var shuffledList = 
        list.
            Select(x => new { Number = r.Next(), Item = x }).
            OrderBy(x => x.Number).
            Select(x => x.Item).
            Take(size); // Assume first @size items is fine

    return shuffledList.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Isn't it same as `OrderBy(x => r.Next())`?

Comment: @Gulshan: Yes it is. Sorting by a random number is not considered to be a very good shuffling algorithm. It works, but it's not as random as it could be.

Comment: No, it's not the same. `OrderBy(x => r.Next())` can potentially put the sort into an infinite loop. This can't.

Comment: @Jim: The `OrderBy` method actually does something like this internally anyway -- generates a key for each item *once* using the projection, stores it and then uses that stored key to sort -- so there's no danger of an infinite loop with the current MS implementation. (Although there's no guarantee that the implementation will be the same on different platforms/versions.)

Comment: @LukeH: Can you give me a pointer to more info on that? What you said makes no sense to me, especially in the context of a comparison function (which is what `r.Next` is being used as here). What am I missing?

Comment: @Jim: Since it's just an implementation detail there's no official documentation, but there's a good discussion of it on Jon Skeet's blog: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts.aspx (see the four articles that comprise the "Ordering" section, and their comments).

Comment: @LukeH: Thanks. I realized on my way home that I was thinking that the parameter was a comparison delegate, not a selection delegate. It's been a bad week.

Answer (score 0):

Anton's got the idea, but you could make it a two-liner:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    var r = new Random();
    return enumerable.OrderBy(x=>r.Next()).ToList();
}
```

Unfortunately, it can't be lazily evaluated because `r` will be out of scope when it does execute. You can create an IEnumerable implementation that encapsulates this code and return that, but that gets more complex.

Comment: Heard this is kind of biased.

Comment: @Gulshan: It shouldn't be *too* bad, although the fact that `OrderBy` is a stable sort could cause problems (and it's possible that `Random` itself might have some inherent bias). The main potential drawback with using `OrderBy` is that it has O(n lg n) time complexity; it's possible to perform a shuffle in O(n), and with no bias.

Comment: This is a really, *really* bad idea. It's possible for something like this to cause an infinite loop in the sorting method.

Comment: @Jim: The current CLR implementation of `OrderBy` only executes the projection once for each element, stores the key and then uses that stored key for ordering, so there's currently no danger of an infinite loop. (Of course, this is relying on an implementation detail that could, theoretically, change.)

Comment: @LukeH: Right. This can't cause an infinite loop. I was thinking of a comparison delegate rather than a selector.

Comment: Why are you `ToList()` -ing when you are returning just IEnumerable? That can create side effects!

Comment: Because if you return just the OrderBy iterator, r will go out of scope and be destroyed before it's ever used. The primary side effect is additional memory; this does not affect the initial enumerable.

Comment: What's up with this "r will go out of scope"? What about variable capturing? It should not be a problem omitting the `.ToList()` in this code snippet...

Comment: -1 This is a managed language, `r` is allocated on the heap and will never "go out of scope", the GC will ensure `r` does not get garbage collected until it is no longer referenced.