# IEnumerable shuffling not random for set of set

Tags: ienumerable, shuffle

I am using shuffling methods from my previous question-

[An extension method on IEnumerable needed for shuffling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807128/an-extension-method-on-ienumerable-needed-for-shuffling)

But when I am using any of these methods for shuffling each elements of an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` by calling something like-

```
SetOfSets.Select(set => set.Shuffle());
```

all the elements are shuffled in same order. How to make it random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `Shuffle` extension method in the linked question instantiates a new `Random` object each time. Since the default constructor uses `Environment.TickCount` to seed the random number generator and this all happens very quickly, all the lists get the same random seed.

You need to instantiate a `Random` instance of your own and pass it to the `Shuffle` overload:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng)
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807128/an-extension-method-on-ienumerable-needed-for-shuffling/5807238#5807238).

Your code, then, would be:

```
Random myRandom = new Random();
SetOfSets.Select(set => set.Shuffle(myRandom));
```