# Random Order of an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ienumerable

I have got an IEnumerable collection as follows

```
var result1 = GetResult1() // Returns 2,4,5,6
```

I have to juggle the elements and create another collection in a random way which should result as follows:

```
var result2 = GetResult2(result1) // Returns 2,4,5,6 in a random order.
// An example output would be 4,6,2,5 in the resultant collection.
```

I have done this by the following means:

```
var result1 = GetResult1();
var random = new Random();
var result2 = result1.OrderBy(order=>random.Next());
```

However the issue with this is that if I access result2 the elements in result2 gets shuffled again, i.e if I output the results of result2 to a console twice, the elements are juggled again.

Can you please advice how to keep this uniform. i.e once I juggle the collection, it should remain the same way thereafter. I have to use lazy evaluation though, since the results are very huge in size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you require lazy evaluation for the results, if that is the case, what you can do is this:

```
var randomNumbers = result1.Select(r => random.Next()).ToArray();
var orderedResult = result1.Zip(randomNumbers, (r, o) => new { Result = r, Order = o })
    .OrderBy(o => o.Order)
    .Select(o => o.Result);
```

By calling `ToArray()` on the random numbers, these will not change. When you finally desire the items in `result1`, you can zip the items with the random numbers, `OrderBy` the random number and `Select` the result.

As long as the items in `result1` come in the same order, the result in `orderedResult` should be the same each time.

Comment: This solution still doubles the original size of the result. Memory-wise, it is roughly equivalent to materializing the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: How is it? if each element of `result1` is a class which contains lots of fields, that is a lot of data. It will only be doubling if each element of `result1` contained one field the size of an int. The solution I have given here will consume memory storing the random numbers, but actually fetching the result data is deferred.

Comment: who said they were objects? Per the OP, they appear to be integers.

Comment: Ah, good observation @Marc, if that is the case then you are right, this solution will practically double the memory usage. If `results1` is sourced from a server, this solution will still limit the hit and amount of data transfer going on.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for a **shuffle algorithm**.

See following SO threads to provide nice extensions method to do the job:

[Is using Random and OrderBy a good shuffle algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/c-is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm)

[An extension method on IEnumerable needed for shuffling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807128/an-extension-method-on-ienumerable-needed-for-shuffling)

---

To answer your question "why is that shuffled again?", it's because of how `OrderBy` works (lazy execution). You could try:

```
var result2 = result1.OrderBy(order=>random.Next()).ToList();
```

Comment: I downvoted because the implementation of his shuffle is not the focus of the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ToList()` like this:

```
var result2 = result1.OrderBy(order=>random.Next()).ToList();
```

Comment: The asker requires lazy/deferred evalution as the items of `result1` are large in size.

Comment: But at some point it must be enumerated, therefore the asker should `ToList()` it as late as possible, and then output the result set to whatever needs it

Comment: What if the asker had some form of pagination? i.e. `Skip(20).Take(10)`, then the amount of data on the clients machine would be less, but if the `OrderBy` was being evaluated before each pagination call, the orders would come out differently.

Comment: Well I can think of one implementation of that: a funny quotes website where quotes are random, but quotes are never shown more than once.