# Why Linq returns only one object when no filters are used

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, ienumerable

I really dont know how to explain this issue. Sorry if its a duplicated post.
This code below works fines. Return to me the product with ID 1031 and when i ran the filter (where) i get the same product (because this one is inside both department and category). OK! But when i remove the where 1031 (seconde line of code) its doesnt works anymore. The IEnumerable attribute called GroupsID has only one value inside (of the department). Its very strange. When put the where product.id == 1031 the attribute has 2 values (49 and 137) but when i remove the where product.id==1031 its only return the first group value (department) for each product. All the products on my list has only one value (49 in most case).

```
   model.Products = from product in context.Products
                        where product.ID == 1031
                        orderby Guid.NewGuid()
                        select new ProductViewModel()
                        {
                            ID = product.ID,
                            FullDescription = product.FullDescription,
                            FileName = (from image in product.ProductImages
                                        select image.FileName).FirstOrDefault(),
                            Price = (from priceList in product.PriceListProducts
                                    select priceList.Price).FirstOrDefault(),
                            GroupsID = (from related in product.ProductGroupRelateds
                                        select related.ProductGroup_ID)
                        };

    CategoryViewModel ctg = model.Categories.Where(categ => categ.FriendlyUrl.ToLower().Equals(filter.ToLower()) || categ.FriendlyUrl.ToLower().Equals(categoryURL.ToLower())).Select(categ => new CategoryViewModel() { ID = categ.ID, Name = categ.Name, FriendlyUrl = categ.FriendlyUrl, Index = categ.Index }).DefaultIfEmpty(null).First();
    if (ctg != null)
        model.Products = model.Products.Where(product => product.GroupsID.Contains(ctg.ID));

    DepartmentViewModel dpt = model.Departments.Where(depto => depto.FriendlyUrl.ToLower().Equals(filter.ToLower()) || depto.FriendlyUrl.ToLower().Equals(departmentURL.ToLower())).Select(depto => new DepartmentViewModel() { ID = depto.ID, Name = depto.Name, FriendlyUrl = depto.FriendlyUrl, Index = depto.Index }).DefaultIfEmpty(null).First();
    if (dpt != null)
        model.Products = model.Products.Where(product => product.GroupsID.Contains(dpt.ID));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `orderby Guid.NewGuid()`?

Comment: @TimS. after removes the orderby its working fine :| thanks for whatever you ever done :D rofl

Comment: Great, I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `orderby Guid.NewGuid()`. It's not a good way to shuffle in general, and in some cases can break your code. Implement your shuffle in a better way, e.g. see [Is using Random and OrderBy a good shuffle algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm) or [An extension method on IEnumerable needed for shuffling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807128/an-extension-method-on-ienumerable-needed-for-shuffling).  The short version is that this is code you can use:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng)
{
    T[] elements = source.ToArray();
    for (int i = elements.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // Swap element "i" with a random earlier element it (or itself)
        // ... except we don't really need to swap it fully, as we can
        // return it immediately, and afterwards it's irrelevant.
        int swapIndex = rng.Next(i + 1);
        yield return elements[swapIndex];
        elements[swapIndex] = elements[i];
    }
}
```