# Multiple string comparison with C#

Tags: c#, string

Let's say I need to compare if string x is "A", "B",  or "C".

With Python, I can use in operator to check this easily.

```python
if x in ["A","B","C"]:
    do something
```

With C#, I can do

```
if (String.Compare(x, "A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || ...)
    do something
```

Can it be something more similar to Python?

### ADDED

I needed to add `System.Linq` in order to use case insensitive Contain().

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Hello {
    public static void Main() {
        var x = "A";

        var strings = new List<string> {"a", "B", "C"};
        if (strings.Contains(x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static class Hello {
    public static bool In(this string source, params string[] list)
    {
        if (null == source) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        return list.Contains(source, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public static void Main() {
        string x = "A";

        if (x.In("a", "B", "C")) {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.Contains<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx) which is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var strings = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
string x = // some string
bool contains = strings.Contains(x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if(contains) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 43):

```
if ((new[]{"A","B","C"}).Contains(x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: Doesnt compile in VS 2019. it thinks thats a string[] which has no Contains defined. If cast to IList it will work

Answer (score 14):

There's a [classic thread here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/what-are-your-favorite-extension-methods-for-c-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow) with an extension method that would do *exactly* what you're looking for.

```
public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
{
  if(null==source) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  return list.Contains(source);
}
```

In response to comment below, if you are only solely concerned with strings then:

```
public static bool In(this string source, params string[] list)
{
    if (null == source) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    return list.Contains(source, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

Which leads to the syntax you're familiar with:

```
if(x.In("A","B","C"))
{
  // do something....
}
```

Note, this is pretty much exactly the same as everyone else has posted only in a syntax closest to what you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<string> possibleMatches = new List<string>{"A", "B", "C"};
if (possibleMatches.Contains(inputString))
{
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure

```
var lst = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
if (lst.Contains(x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that C# 9.0 has [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/patterns3#pattern-combinators), there's a new, elegant way to do that:

```
if (x is "A" or "B" or "C") { ... }
```

Or, if you need case-insensitivity:

```
if (x.ToUpperInvariant() is "A" or "B" or "C") { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet would be the [Select Case (switch in C#)](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Compared%E2%80%94Select_Case) statement.

Edit: Sorry Select Case is VB.NET (my usual language) and it is switch in C#.

Comment: I updated it with the C# command. Wasn't aware of Select Case being limited to VB.NET.

Comment: what criteria to you use to say using a switch (or select) is "Best"?

Answer (score -2):

There are a couple of approaches to this, I would suggest you do something like:

```
 private const string _searched = "A|B|C|";
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string search = "B" + "|";
     if (_searched.IndexOf(search) > -1)
     {
         //do something
     }
 }
```

There are a lot of other ways to handle this, and the larger your search field gets, the more likely using an array, hashtable or collection becomes valueable. As long as your field of possibilities remains small, the use of a simple string is going to be your best performance. All of the overhead of more complex arrays or objects (or arrays of objects...) is unnecessary.