# ASP.net how to extend a control or collection

Tags: asp.net, list, function

I am attempting to extend a List. When using Visual Studio there are the different code hints for all the functions I can use with a List object. How can I extend the functionality of the List to show my new function?

```
public class ListExtensionHelper<T> : System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
{
    public List<T> AwesomeFunction<T>()
    {
    }
}
```

For the life of me I could not find anything online on how I would do it for a List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to add `AwesomeFunction` as an extension method to a regular List object, then you need to define an extension method in a static class:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<T> AwesomeFunction<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
    }
}
```

Otherwise, the code you have should work; if you instantiate the ListExtensionHelper class, it should have all the functions of List as well as AwesomeFunction.

Comment: It looks like I was just missing the `this` within the function paramenters. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), rather than inheritance.

There are some really good examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/271398/328193).  There's also a really good library of extensions available [here](http://umbrella.codeplex.com/).

<soapbox>
One of my personal favorites that I use is this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
  public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string s)
  {
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
  }
}
```

It's ridiculously simple, but a huge pet peeve of mine is having to write:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(someVariable))
```

as opposed to:

```
if (someVariable.IsNullOrEmpty())
```

For me it's just a matter of being a natural construct of my native language.  The built-in method sounds like:

> object verb subject

whereas mine sounds like:

> subject verb

It's probably silly, but when I want to act upon a subject it just makes more sense for me to start with the subject :)
</soapbox>