# Get the parameter prefix in ADO.NET

Tags: .net, database, ado.net, factory, abstract

I want to generate several SQL statements based on a column list using the column names as parameters.

**Edit**: C#

```
var columns = new string[] { "COL1", "COL2" };
var tableName = "TABLE_1";
var prefix = "@"; // TODO get this from the provider factory

string sqlInsert = string.Format(
    "INSERT INTO {0}\n( {1}) VALUES\n({2})",
    tableName,
    string.Join(",  ", columns),
    string.Join(", ", columns.Select(c => prefix + c)));
```

Generated SQL:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1
( COL1,  COL2) VALUES
(@COL1, @COL2)
```

This works with the SqlClient. But I'm using the abstract classes in System.Data (`DbCommand`, `DbParameter`, etc.) and different data providers such as Oracle, MySQL, Postgres etc based on the connection string settings in the app.config. Thus I need to know which prefix I have to use. For MS-SQL it is the `@`, Oracle uses the `:`, the rest I actually don't know.

Is there a way to get this prefix character from the provider factory?

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.Instance`doesn't have such an information or at least I couldn't find it.

Otherwise, can you give me a list for the common databases?

**Edit**: The target platforms are .NET 2 to .NET 4 and the information should be available through the provider factory.

Comment: Can you provide the code you used to generate the SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, but I cannot reproduce how I found it:

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2007/09/06/about-parametermarkerformat/

The DbConnection can provide a schema table that also contains the correct format strings for creating command parameter names, **except for SqlClient!!**

```
DbProviderFactory myFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(myProviderName);

using (DbConnection myConnection = myFactory.CreateConnection())
{
    myConnection.ConnectionString = mySettings.ConnectionString;
    myConnection.Open();

    string parameterMarker = myConnection
        .GetSchema(DbMetaDataCollectionNames.DataSourceInformation)
        .Rows[0][DbMetaDataColumnNames.ParameterMarkerFormat].ToString();

    myConnection.Close();
}
```

For `SqlCclient` `parameterMarker` is `{0}` but should be `@{0}`. I'll investigate a bit more to find out what is contained in the other schema table columns.

Comment: `ParameterMarkerPattern` is `{0}` because `@` is already included in `ParameterNamePattern`, so you should check both.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 [DbCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder) methods that will help you, [GetParameterName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.getparametername) and [GetParameterPlaceholder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.getparameterplaceholder). These are protected, so you'll need a little reflection to use them.

Check out my answer to the following question for an implementation (also included in the [DbExtensions](http://maxtoroq.github.io/DbExtensions/) library):

[What are your favorite extension methods for C#? (codeplex.com/extensionoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/what-are-your-favorite-extension-methods-for-c-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow/2550726#2550726)