# Dapper.net Oracle parameter

Tags: oracle, dapper

I am trying to use Dapper.net with Oracle.

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212992/using-dapper-with-oracle) i understood that we could use parameters with no prefixes and dapper would then work for both `sql server`and `oracle`

I'm having a hard time making it to work without the explicit oracle named parameters prefix `:`

The following query

```
sqlConnection.Query("Select * FROM document WHERE id = param1", new { param1 = 963 });
```

Throws `ORA-00904: "PARAM1": invalid identifier`

If i try with the `@` prefix it throws `ORA-00936: missing expression`

If i use the `:` prefix it works as expected. But **i do not want my queries to be dependent** (as far as possible) **upon Oracle or Sql Server**.

I am using the latest nuget package version Dapper.dll 1.12.1.1

What am I doing wrong or did i misunderstand this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212992/using-dapper-with-oracle)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you misunderstood the post. The SQL is passed through as-is, and must contain the correct `:param1` or `@param1` etc. The "no prefix *at all*" is talking about the code that **you don't see** - specifically, making sure that the code does (via some mechanism):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("param1", 963);
```

vs

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", 963);
```

vs

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(":param1", 963);
```

The first (no prefix) is the correct and preferred option.

If you want the SQL in your code to be parameter agnostic, you could use the information from here: [Get the parameter prefix in ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904430/get-the-parameter-prefix-in-ado-net)

The SQL is rarely close enough, however, that just looking up the parameter prefix will fix all problems.

Comment: I know this is an old post, and Contrib probably came out after it.  How does your answer fit with Dapper.Contrib, where I don't manage that character?  That leaves dropping Contrib, and either swapping out the @ character, or using String.Format to inject the literal values into the SQL statements.