# Using : instead of @ for query parameters

Tags: sql-server, dapper

I have a rather big application using dapper and Oracle. Now, I want to support SQL Server.

The problem is that all my queries are written with `:` and not with `@`, so SQL Server complains:

> Incorrect syntax near ':'

Is it possible to tell Dapper that it should replace `:` with `@` or do I have to do that in my own code?

Comment: you should manually do this in code.

Comment: Dapper is just a *very thin* layer on top of your `SqlConnection` or `OracleConnection` - I highly doubt it has any means of replacing parameter naming conventions. That would be something a full ORM like Entity Framework would probably handle for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that this is indeed impossible directly with dapper :

[Dapper.net Oracle parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962405/dapper-net-oracle-parameter)

[Using Dapper with Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212992/using-dapper-with-oracle)

Sorry for the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This is not built in, but you could provide it relatively simply by writing a custom extension method and doing whatever tweaks you need:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyMagicQuery<T>(this IDbConnection conn,
    string query, object args = ...)
{
    query = RunSomeRegexReplace(query);
    return conn.Query<T>(query, args, ...);
}
```

However, while the regex for this is not particularly taxing, the bigger problem is that T/SQL and PL/SQL are both **distinct variants** of SQL. Many features will not work at all when given a simple direct translation. Other features may work, but require different syntax. A third group of features may work syntactically but **give different results** (yes, really), or have very different performance characteristics unless re-written to exploit RDBMS-specific preferences.

Fundamentally, changing between RDBMS is a lot more than just changing `@` to `:`.