# How to create a Between Extension Method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have a variable whose value is populated at runtime. I want to check whether that value is between two same datatype values (say lowest and highest) or not using an Extension Method.

I want to check like

```
int a = 2; //here static but is can be changed at runtime

if(a.Between(0,8))
   DoSomething();
else
   DoNothing();
```

If `a` is 0 or 8 or any value between them, it should return `true`.

If `a` is (-1 or less) or (9 or greater) then it should return `false`

i want to create an extension method like

```
public static bool Between<T1>(this T1 val1, T1 lowest, T1 highest) where ????
{
    What code to write here???? 
}
```

Comment: Just a remark : this has nothing to do with Linq, it's just "Fluent"

Comment: Many people think linq means extension methods, as the linq ones are the one people are most familiar with. A total misunderstanding, but quite common.

Comment: @Falanwe and Raphael: Thanks and retagged it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public static bool Between<T>(this T actual, T lower, T upper) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return actual.CompareTo(lower) >= 0 && actual.CompareTo(upper) <= 0;
}
```

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271444/1100080)

Or if you want to do it on a collection you can do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Between<TSource, TResult>
(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector,
    TResult lowest, TResult highest
)
    where TResult : IComparable<TResult>
{
    return source.OrderBy(selector).
        SkipWhile(s => selector.Invoke(s).CompareTo(lowest) < 0).
        TakeWhile(s => selector.Invoke(s).CompareTo(highest) <= 0 );
}
```

Reference [here](http://kendoll.net/c_sharp_linq_extension_method_for_values_between_a_range)

Usage:

```
var tenTo40 = list.Between(s => s, 10, 40);
```

Comment: Last part from here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310581/A-Between-extension-method-for-Linq-in-Csharp

Comment: Oops.. I did forget the references. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Edited your answer to include <= with highest comparison because i want to check for both values inclusive

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
public static bool Between<T1, T2>(this T1 val1, T2 lowest, T2 highest) where T1 : IComparable where T2 : IComparable {
    return val1.CompareTo(lowest) > 0 && val1.CompareTo(highest) < 0;
}
```

Comment: i think it's `<=` isntead of `<` and `>=` isntead of `>`

Answer (score 1):

Mixing types will make it harder, eg. if T1 is datetime and t2 is int then what behaviour do you expect?

Using only one type all the way you can use the IComparable interface

```
public static bool Between<T>(this T self, T lower,T higher) where T : IComparable
{
    return self.CompareTo(lower) >= 0 && self.CompareTo(higher) <= 0;
}
```