# Is there a simpler way to do this if statement in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
if (model.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "05" || 
    model.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "06")
```

I have more like this. Is there a more clean way to code this where I don't have to repeat model.PartitionKey twice ?

Comment: Anne, you should make clear the _reason_ you need it. Because of performance? Code readability? To make it easy to extend (for example with values to compare that come from configuration)? Answers shot to every direction but often they're not compatible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about this:

```
if (new string[]{"05", "06"}.Contains(model.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2))
    // ...
```

That leaves you at liberty to keep the strings you are looking for in a nice list...

```
var lookingFor = new string[]{"05", "06"};
var substring = model.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2);
if (lookingFor.Contains(substring))
{
    // ...
}
```

This will help a lot if the list of strings you are looking for gets longer than just two... Also, you can then add this to a set (`HashSet<string>`) for more efficient lookup - but test this first, as overhead can eat up gains.

Comment: You may also reduce `new string[] { ... }` to `new [] { ... }`.

Comment: @Joey, haha! love your code edit comment ;) I wonder how those quotes got messed up...

Answer (score 9):

For such kind of cases I use an Extension Method

```
public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
{
   if (source = null)
       throw new NullReferenceException("Source is Null");

   return list.Contains(source);
}
```

and call it as

```
if (model.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2).In("05", "06"))
```

Being an Extension Method we can call it for all types like

```
if(myintegervariable.In(3, 4));
```

OR

```
if(mybytevariable.In(23, 56, 34, 43, 87, 155));
```

Comment: This extension method is quite reusable. Although it is just the inverse of `Contains`, it is much more readable in cases like this.

Comment: _"i have created for myself"_ That's the most popular extension method. http://stackoverflow.com/a/833477/284240

Answer (score 7):

```
var keyString = model.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2);
if (keyString == "05" || keyString == "06")
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That's not optimization but obfuscation.

Comment: Doesn't really solve the problem, if anything your introducing *more* code to the equation.

Comment: The OP merely wanted to avoid repeating model.PartitionKey twice. How is doing that once only then saving the result not optimization?

Comment: Tim, James: It fits the question exactly (»won't have to repeat model.PartitionKey twice«) and extracting common subexpressions into a local variable is a viable optimisation. And I'd argue that it's not harder to read – what `temp` is, is pretty clear, especially so close together and the condition *is* easier to read.

Comment: @Joey: `temp` is never good naming. Consider that this variable might be used across a huge method. The point is, `modelPkYear` would be more fail-safe.

Comment: @Tim I typed my solution in around 3 seconds - of course I wouldn't normally use 'temp' as a variable name, but in this situation, without knowing the real meaning of the original expression, and as a piece of demonstration code, I felt it fit the bill. Anyway, rather than hating, feel free to change it to something more meaningful if you like!

Comment: @Surfbutler: But you've written your answer 15 minutes ago. So you had 15 minutes to improve it.

Comment: @Tim: Changed 'temp' changed to 'subString'.

Comment: @Surfbutler: I would have preferred `modelPkYear` as mentioned(since i assume that it's the two digit year) but anyway, undone downvote

Comment: @Surfbutler still far too generic, `subString` doesn't make it any clearer as to what information variable is holding. Something like `keyString` is more clear.

Comment: Now changed variable name to 'keyString' :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised nobody offered switch as a possible alternative :)

```
switch (model.PartitionKey.SubString(2,2)) {
  case "05":
  case "06":
    // do stuff
    break;
  // other cases
  default:
    // like an else
}
```

You can read more about it at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

Comment: +1 for introducing something completely different. The problem is, that the question is not clear enough to know if this solution fits in. If there are more constants to be compared with, it may even be a very nice solution.

Comment: I don't feel replacing the existing code to a switch statement is going to make the OP's life any easier. If anything, this would probably become more of a hinderance having to write a switch statement all over the place. Unless of course it's tucked away into a re-usable method.

Answer (score 3):

You can save the substring in a variable:

```
var substring = model.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2);
if (substring == "05" || substring == "06")
```

Or you could use a regular expression:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch("^..0[56]", model.PartitionKey))
```

This probably depends a bit on how easily you can understand a regex while reading code.

Comment: -1 for a regex, IMO you should never use a regex for simple string manipulations like this. If anything using a regex will *complicate* the statement more.

Comment: I would use a simpler regex, eg `^..(?:05|06)`, if I went that route.. also care for `.` not matching everything in some languages.

Comment: James, that's quite subjective, I think. In this case I'd rather read a simple regex (which *is* trivial to understand) than a more complex statement. But as said, this depends a bit on your familiarity with regular expressions.

Comment: pst, introducing non-capturing groups adds more clutter than a character class, I guess.

Comment: `I'd rather read a simple regex` ... in general, maybe yes. Subjective, indeed. However, in _this_ particular case, calling the original expression a "complex" statement is quite a stretch.

Comment: @Joey/pst - I did say *IMO*, however, in general I still don't believe recommending a regex for something as trivial as this is a *simpler* alternative. Not only that, but could also hinder performance based on how intensive the regex is.

Answer (score 1):

To aid readibility you could extract the `Substring` out into a variable and then test that:

```
var partitionKeyBits = model.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2);

if (partitionKeyBits == "05" || partitionKeyBits == "06") {

}
```

But otherwise that is about it.

Answer (score 0):

`if (new []{"05", "06"}.Contains(model.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2))`

the syntax might be far off, corrections are welcome :)

Edit: `new []`

Comment: There is a missing `new []` for the array creation.

Comment: Agree that is removes the duplicated `model.PartitionKey.Substring` but doesn't feel very "dot-net-ish" (especially with the need for `new[]`).  Not sure if from a readability standpoint this is a great choice.

Comment: That said, would be awesome if you could do `['05, '06'].include? model.PartitionKey.Substring(2,2)` ;)

Comment: Thanks Michael. actually, thats what i had in mind initially.. isnT it practically the same thing though?