# How to improve this code using c#

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a simpler way to do this if statement in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358004/is-there-a-simpler-way-to-do-this-if-statement-in-c-sharp)

I have this code:

```
while ((txtSource.Text[startPos].ToString() == " ") || 
       (txtSource.Text[startPos].ToString() == ",") || 
       (txtSource.Text[startPos].ToString() == ".")))
        {
            // do something
        }
```

is there any way to do the above like for instance:

```
while (!txtSource.Text[startPos].ToString() in (" ",",","."))
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Define *improve*.

Comment: Instead of doing `.ToString()`, just do `txtSource.Text[startPos] == ','` (with single quotes).  Also consider using a switch statement.

Comment: ok, let's say that to shorten the code, to make it clearer :)

Comment: You are right @Matthew, thanks for the tip! vote up!

Comment: @Somebody - The code is already clear.  Why do you want to make it more complicated?  If the code does what you want, what exactly is the problem, sometimes simple is better.

Comment: @Ramhound don't be silly. Every solution is better when complicated with LINQ!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while ((new char[] {' ', ',', '.'}).Contains(txtSource.Text[startPos]))
```

Answer (score 5):

LINQ `Any()` for help:

```
string text = "some text";
char[] controlChars = { ' ', ',', '.' };
int index = 1;
bool passed = controlChars.Any(c => c == text[index]);
```

Comment: While I question the reasons the author wants a "better" way to improve their code, this is an elegant solution, and does provide some clarity to the code.

Answer (score 4):

```
string[] SearchList =  {" ",",","."};

while (SearchList.Contains(txtSource.Text[startPos].ToString() ))
{
   // Do Something
}
```

Comment: Nice David! thank you :)

Comment: I like @SteveDog's format better, though.  He did the same thing in one line of code, and (more properly than my answer) used chars, which also shortened it up and eliminate the need for .ToString().

Answer (score 4):

```
private static bool IsStopChar(char c)
{
  switch (c)
  {
    case ' ':
    case ',':
    case '.':
      return false;
    default:
      return true;
  }
}

//...

  while (!IsStopChar(txtSource.Text[startPos]))
  {
    //...
  }
```

With this solution you avoid collection iteration, memory allocation, initialization,...
Modifying cases remains easy.

Comment: -1 need moar LINQ! Just kidding, I upvoted ... this is very straight forward and readable. Shorter is not always better.