# How can I compare multiple variables to a single condition?

Tags: c#, if-statement, collections

I have this:

```
if (input.Text.ToUpper() == "STOP")
```

But there are so many possible values  that I wouldn't be able to specify them all separately like this:

```
if (input.Text.ToUpper() == "STOP" || input.Text.ToUpper() == "END")
```

Is there a way that you can do something like this:

```
if (input.Text.ToUpper() == "STOP", "END", "NO", "YES")
```

So that using STOP, END, NO, or YES will do the task?

Using any contains won't work, other times accepted words will have the word STOP and END in them.

Comment: Contains does NOT match words that contain the string! So Contain can work.

Answer (score 16):

You could use a collection like array and [`Enumerable.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx):

```
var words = new[]{ "STOP", "END", "NO", "YES" };
if(words.Contains(input.Text.ToUpper()))
{
     // ...      
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Perfect situation for a string extension

Add this to a new file

```
namespace appUtils
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static bool In(this string s, params string[] values)
        {
            return values.Any(x => x.Equals(s));
        }
    }
}
```

and call from your code in this way

```
if(input.Text.In("STOP", "END", "NO", "YES") == true)
   // ... do your stuff
```

Comment: I think this is ideal. I would add a StringComparison argument to your extension method and your Equals check.

Comment: Even better would be a generic `In`-extension: http://stackoverflow.com/a/833477/284240

Answer (score 4):

you can do...

```
if(new[]{ "STOP", "END", "NO", "YES" }.Contains(input.Text.ToUpper()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hold an array of the possible words and match it with the `Contains` method:

```
string[] validInput = new string[] { "STOP", "END", "NO", "YES" };

// input is the input you have
if (validInput.Contains(input.Text.ToUpper()))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var tasks = new List<string> { "STOP", "END", "NO", "YES" };
        tasks.Contains(input.Text.ToUpper());
```

looks better

```
        var tasks = new List<string> { "stop", "end", "no", "yes" };
        tasks.Exists(x => string.Equals(x, input.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ to do this. That way if you have both STOP and END in your string, it will pick up on both of them:

```
var myStringArray= new[]{ "STOP", "END", "NO", "YES" };
var query = myString.Any(x => myStringArray.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

create extension:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static bool EqualsAny(this string item, params string[] array)
    {
        return array.Any(s => item.ToUpper() == s.ToUpper());
    }
}
```

using:

```
if (inputText.EqualsAny("STOP", "END", "NO", "YES"))
```