# What is the C# equivalent of the Oracle IN statement?

Tags: c#, oracle, syntax

How would I check if a variable is one of a few values?

Where `IN` in Oracle it would read like

```
where strVar in ('A','H','X','Z')
```

without having to write

```
if (strVar == "A" || strVar == "H" || strVar == "X" || strVar =="Z")
```

---

*editted to change variable name*

Comment: write yourself an IN method :)

Comment: @Randy: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/833477/284240)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be enough for you:

```
if(new string[]{"A","B",".."}.Contains(strVar)) {
    .... CONTAINS ...
}
```

can use also

```
if(new string[]{"A","B",".."}.Any(strVar)) {
    .... CONTAINS ...
}
```

but `Contains` works also on `C# 2.0`, instead `Any` no.

**EDIT**

As correctly pointed out @brendan, get rid of `var` named variable, that is `C#` keyword, let's avoid creating confusion.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use var as a variable name because that's a C# keyword - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx , var var = "A"; appears to work but that's just strange to read.

Comment: I'd recommend using `needle` and `haystack` as local variable names in smaller questions and answers like these.

Answer (score 2):

This should probably be you best bet:

```
if ("hxza".Contains(value))
```

I made somes "**test speed**" with some diferents ways to do what you whant to do.

*You can see the **code at bottom**. Note that **X is the number of time** i repeat the test to make an average*

Result for X = 1:

```
Average of ticks for test7 : 4
Average of ticks for test2 : 5
Average of ticks for test10 : 6
Average of ticks for test9 : 7
Average of ticks for test4 : 19
Average of ticks for test8 : 35
Average of ticks for test6 : 451
Average of ticks for test5 : 2711
Average of ticks for test1 : 3146
Average of ticks for test3 : 8569
```

Result for X = 100:

```
Average of ticks for test2 : 3
Average of ticks for test7 : 3
Average of ticks for test10 : 3
Average of ticks for test9 : 5
Average of ticks for test4 : 5
Average of ticks for test8 : 5
Average of ticks for test6 : 11
Average of ticks for test3 : 20
Average of ticks for test5 : 23
Average of ticks for test1 : 35
```

Result for X = 100 000:

```
Average of ticks for test2 : 3
Average of ticks for test7 : 3
Average of ticks for test5 : 3
Average of ticks for test1 : 3
Average of ticks for test6 : 3
Average of ticks for test10 : 3
Average of ticks for test9 : 5
Average of ticks for test4 : 5
Average of ticks for test8 : 5
Average of ticks for test3 : 5
```

So we could tell that test 2, 7 and 10 are good way to make what you want:

```
//test2
if (value == 'a' || value == 'h' || value == 'x' || value == 'z')

//test7
if (value == 'h' || value == 'x' || value == 'z' || value == 'a')

//test10
if ("hxza".Contains(value))
```

See the code:

```
            char value = 'a';
            Dictionary<string, long> tests = new Dictionary<string, long>()
            {
                {"test1", 0},
                {"test2", 0},
                {"test3", 0},
                {"test4", 0},
                {"test5", 0},
                {"test6", 0},
                {"test7", 0},
                {"test8", 0},
                {"test9", 0},
                {"test10", 0}
            };
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            // tested with 1, 100 and 100 000
            long X = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
            {
                watch.Start();
                if ("ahxz".Any(c => c == value))
                {
                }
                watch.Stop();
                tests["test1"] += watch.ElapsedTicks;
                watch.Reset();

                watch.Start();
                if (value == 'a' || value == 'h' || value == 'x' || value == 'z')
                {
                }
                watch.Stop();
                tests["test2"] += watch.ElapsedTicks;
                watch.Reset();

                watch.Start();
                if (new[] { 'a', 'h', 'x', 'z' }.Contains(value))
                {
                }
                watch.Stop();
                tests["test3"] += watch.ElapsedTicks;
                watch.Reset();

                watch.Start();
                if (new[] { 'a', 'h', 'x', 'z' }.Contains(value))
                {
                }
                watch.Stop();
                tests["test4"] += watch.ElapsedTicks;
                watch.Reset();

                watch.Start();
                if ("ahxz".Contains(value))
                {
                }
                watch.Stop();
                tests["test5"] += watch.ElapsedTicks;
                watch.Reset();

                watch.Start();
                if ("hxza".Any(c => c == value))
                {
                }
                watch.Stop();
                tests["test6"] += watch.ElapsedTicks;
                watch.Reset();

                watch.Start();
                if (value == 'h' || value == 'x' || value == 'z' || value == 'a')
                {
                }
                watch.Stop();
                tests["test7"] += watch.ElapsedTicks;
                watch.Reset();

                watch.Start();
                if (new[] { 'h', 'x', 'z', 'a' }.Contains(value))
                {
                }
                watch.Stop();
                tests["test8"] += watch.ElapsedTicks;
                watch.Reset();

                watch.Start();
                if (new[] { 'h', 'x', 'z', 'a' }.Contains(value))
                {
                }
                watch.Stop();
                tests["test9"] += watch.ElapsedTicks;
                watch.Reset();

                watch.Start();
                if ("hxza".Contains(value))
                {
                }
                watch.Stop();
                tests["test10"] += watch.ElapsedTicks;
                watch.Reset();
            }

            foreach (var test in tests.OrderBy(p => p.Value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Average of ticks for {0} : {1}\n", test.Key, test.Value / nbrOfTimes);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any context:

`new [] {'A','H','X','Z'}.Contains(var);`

Comment: This would, of course, be for finding a char.  I didn't make a mistake.  You saw nothing.