# Shortcut to use boolean operators on multiple values

Tags: c#

First off, sorry if the title isn't clear or descriptive; I didn't know what to write exactly.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this operation:

```
bool result = variable1.innerValue.level2.innerValue == 1 || 
              variable1.innerValue.level2.innerValue == 2 || 
              variable1.innerValue.level2.innerValue == 3;
```

We can't write something like:

```
bool result = variable1.innerValue.level2.innerValue == (1 || 2 || 3);
```

This will give a syntax error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a collection as placeholder and [`Enumerable.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx):

```
if(new[]{1, 2, 3}.Contains(variable1.innerValue.level2.innerValue))
{

}
```

or, for what it's worth, this extension:

```
public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
{
  if(null==source) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  return list.Contains(source);
}
```

which enables you to write this:

```
if(variable1.innerValue.level2.innerValue.In(1, 2, 3))
{

}
```

[What are your favorite extension methods for C#? (codeplex.com/extensionoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/what-are-your-favorite-extension-methods-for-c-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow)

Comment: As long as there are only a few values, an array is better. But if the list of values becomes big enough, consider switching to `HashSet<T>.Contains`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case. you can do `Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Contains(variable1.innerValue.level2.innerValue)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Linq;
...
bool result = new[] {1, 2, 3}.Contains(variable1.innerValue.level2.innerValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var listToCheck = new int[]{1,2,3};
var innerValue = variable1.innerValue.level2.innerValue;

bool result = listToCheck.Contains(innerValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the first thing that comes to my mind is the good old [Introduce Explaining Variable](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceExplainingVariable.html) refactoring, which not only reduces the duplication but also makes your code more self-explanatory:

```
var innerValue = variable1.innerValue.level2.innerValue;
bool result = innerValue == 1 || innerValue == 2 || innerValue == 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
(new List<int>(){1,2,3}).Exists(i=>i == variable1.innerValue.level2.innerValue)
```