# Why <T> is placed after method name for some extension methods in C#

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, generic-type-argument

I was looking at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/what-are-your-favorite-extension-methods-for-c-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow#answer-833477) of stackoverflow to learn more about C# extension methods. I couldn't understand the part `<T>` after the method name. To be more exact:

```
public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
{
  if(null==source) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  return list.Contains(source);
}
```

I can understand `T` refers generic name for any class. Why do we need `<T>` after the method name for this extension method?

Comment: Otherwise it wouldn't be a  generic extension method. Now you can use it with any type. Not the `T` indicates a generic type, you could also call it `TheType` if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the method needs to be generic in order to operate on instances of any given type, represented by `T`. The `<T>` just tells the compiler that this method is generic with a type parameter `T`. If you leave it out, the compiler will treat `T` as an actual type, which of course for this purpose it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

The `T` by itself doesn't mean it's generic. If you have the <> after the name, that means it's generic, with a generic parameter which you call `T` in this case.

```
public static bool In<ParameterType>(this ParameterType source, params ParameterType[] list)
{
  if(null==source) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  return list.Contains(source);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It allows apply this extension method to any type, due to method is generic. But checking `if(null==source)` assumes method will work with references types. Actually, you may get NRE and I suggest to add checking for null incoming list parameter.

Comment: Why should he check for `nulls`? If the list is null it will raise a `NullReferenceException` what is desired.

Comment: return list.Contains(source); - if list is null he will get Null Reference exception (NRE). In method may return `false if list is null

Comment: Yes, of course. The same happens always and it is the desired behaviour if someone tries to do something with `null`.

Comment: It is only suggestion to return false, instead of NRE