# IDbCommand named parameters for both MySQL and SQL Server

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I've been trying to create some DB independent code like the following:

```
IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "...";

IDbDataParameter param1 = command.CreateParameter();
param1.ParameterName = "param1";
param1.Value = "value";
command.Parameters.Add(param1);
```

The command text that works for mysql is:

```
select * from mytable where field1 = ?param1
```

The command text that works for sqlserver is:

```
select * from mytable where field1 = @param1
```

Is there some form that will work for both?

EDIT:

- SQL Server 2008R2
- MySQL 5.0.X

Comment: Note that i've edited my answer to provide a dynamic approach using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, i think there's no such method. So you have to provide your own:

```
public static String GetProviderParameter(string paramName, IDbConnection con)
{
    string prefix = "";
    if(con is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)
        prefix = "@";
    else if(con is System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection)
        prefix =  "?";
    else if(con is System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection)
        prefix =  "?";
    else if(con is MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection)
        prefix =  "?";

    return prefix + paramName;
}
```

Usage:

```
param1.ParameterName = GetProviderParameter("param1", connection);
```

Or you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2550726/284240) extension which uses reflection to use the `protected` method `GetParameterName` from the `DbCommandBuilder` class:

```
public static class Db
{
    static readonly Func<DbConnection, DbProviderFactory> getDbProviderFactory = 
        (Func<DbConnection, DbProviderFactory>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<DbConnection, DbProviderFactory>), typeof(DbConnection).GetProperty("DbProviderFactory", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetGetMethod(true));
    static readonly Func<DbCommandBuilder, string, string> getParameterName =
        (Func<DbCommandBuilder, string, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<DbCommandBuilder, string, string>), typeof(DbCommandBuilder).GetMethod("GetParameterName", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null));

    public static DbProviderFactory GetProviderFactory(this DbConnection connection)
    {
        return getDbProviderFactory(connection);
    }

    public static string GetParameterName(this DbConnection connection, string paramName)
    {
        DbCommandBuilder builder = GetProviderFactory(connection).CreateCommandBuilder();

        return getParameterName(builder, paramName);
    }
}
```

Then it's simple as:

```
param1.ParameterName = connection.GetParameterName("param1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for both:

```
select * from mytable where field1 = @param1
```

See the documentation for [MySql here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html).

Comment: You're right, this works for 5.1.x+... unfortunately I've got to use 5.0.x