# LINQ Expression - Dynamic From & Where Clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following list of integers that I need to extract varying lists of integers containing numbers from say 2-4 numbers in count. The code below will extract lists with only 2 numbers.

```
var numList = new List<int> { 5, 20, 1, 7, 19, 3, 15, 60, 3, 21, 57, 9 };

var selectedNums = (from n1 in numList
                    from n2 in numList
                    where (n1 > 10) && (n2 > 10)
                    select new { n1, n2 }).ToList();
```

Is there any way to build up this Linq expression dynamically so that if I wanted lists of 3 numbers it would be compiled as below, this would save me having to package the similar expression inside a different method.

```
var selectedNums = (from n1 in numList
                    from n2 in numList
                    from n3 in numList
                    where (n1 > 10) && (n2 > 10) && (n3 > 10)
                    select new { n1, n2, n3 }).ToList();
```

Comment: See: [Computing a Cartesian Product with LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx)

Comment: I've read this article but can't see how it would help my case

Comment: The bit beginning with "But what do you do if you do not know how many sequences there are at compile time?" is *exactly* what you need. You can always repeat the same sequence with `Enumerable.Repeat`.

Comment: If LINQ is not an actual requirement then consider the class given in [this blog](http://www.felicepollano.com/2011/08/12/HelperClassForTheCartesianProductOfMoreThanTwoArrays.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all good questions the way to solve this is with Linq and with Recursion!

```
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permutation<T>(int count, IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        if(count == 1)
        {
            foreach(var i in sequence)
            {
                yield return new [] { i };
            }
            yield break;
        }


        foreach(var inner in Permutation(count - 1, sequence))
        foreach(var i in sequence)
        {
            yield return inner.Concat(new [] { i });
        }        
    }

var foo = Permutation<int>(3, numList.Where(x => x > 10));
```

Comment: I've tried this but there seems to be errors with the syntax, "Permuation" is spelled differently and some closing ")" are missing, can't get it to build

Comment: This code is a good candidate for [mega-list of useful helper extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/271398/395718).

Comment: Just googled this a bit, and I believe the proper name of the method should be something like  `CartesianPower` instead of `Permutation`.

Answer (score 0):

**[Edited]**

You can combine joins and where clauses with loops and conditions, like that:

```
var q = numList.Where(x => x > 10).Select(x => new List<int>{ x });

for(i = 1; i <= numToTake; ++i)
  q = q.Join(numList.Where(x => x > 10), x=> 0, y => 0, (x, y) => { x.Add(y); return x; });
```

(that returns a List instead of an anonymous object)

Edit 2: Thanks Aron for the comment.

Comment: Sorry guys, but I'm new to Linq and figuring out how either of these 2 suggestions will work for me is way over my head at the moment, I don't need to join 2 lists, I need to create extracted lists of integers with varying count values, as you can see from the above the first expression will have integers list with 2 numbers each, the second expression will have 3 numbers each

Comment: When I try to run this I get this error on build - Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TOuter>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>, System.Func<TOuter,TKey>, System.Func<TInner,TKey>, System.Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Its because `List.Add` is `void` return. You can "fix" it with `(x, y) => { x.Add(y); return x; }`. But I would advise against using Linq in this way, since functional programming with mutables is just a bit insane. Besides, with permutations, you would very quickly use up a lot of memory, my solution is Lazy evaluated, and can be much more memory efficient.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway, I think I'll stick to using multiple expressions to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it can help you but an idea how I achieved the same dynamic result based on condition.

```
var q=(from n in context.TableName
       .......);

if(x!=null) //this can be the condition (you can have yours)
var final=q.Select(i=>i....); //I am using q again here
```

I am not sure what will be the performance.