# How to insert line break in c# class's properties(passing its value to sql server)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008-r2

I am making a column in my table as `History` which needs to store data like below:

```
28/05/2013: Service_Id = 1, Mapping_Id = 3, Comment = abcxyz
29/05/2013: Service_Id = 1, Mapping_Id = 3, Comment = changeddata
```

Now I don't know how to make data look like this that is with line break in c# code so that it is stored in sql server and when I retrieve data it should look like above only.

Comment: You can also use `\r\n` for new line

Comment: Why would you not have separate rows in your table, one for each line of history information?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I think I will not needed new line data in db. But in case if I needed that So I asked.

Comment: Why not work out whether or not you need it first? It sounds like you've naturally got separate rows to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just concatenate with `Environment.NewLine`, or use `StringBuilder` to append lines.

It won't necessarily *look* like that in SQL, say, Management Studio, as the fields aren't displayed that way, but anywhere the content is displayed where newlines are respected then it will be formatted as such.

Comment: you can change output to text instead of datagrid in management studio using ctrl-t and you can see line breaks in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Try as

```
// Sample for the Environment.NewLine property 
 using System;

 class Sample 
 {
   public static void Main() 
   {
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("NewLine: {0}  first line{0}  second line{0}  third line",
                      Environment.NewLine);
   }
 }
/*
 This example produces the following results:

 NewLine:
 first line
 second line
 third line
*/
```

[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

[Stackoverflow Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085739/how-to-insert-newline-in-string-literal)