# How to put a string in a newline?

Tags: c#, .net, line-breaks, stringbuilder

I am working with strings in C#. I have a string like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(ValidatorMethod1());
sb.AppendLine(ValidatorMethod2());
```

after "sb" is called on `ValidatorMethod1()`, I call a `ValidatorMethod2()` as shown, both returns a error message as a string based on a condition. If `ValidatorMethod1()` and `ValidatorMethod2()` returns a error msg, then all is fine. But if `ValidatorMethod2()` fails, then the length of the error message returned from `ValidatorMethod2(`) is "0", but still a line is appended with "sb" and thus a empty error line is appended after `ValidatorMethod1()`'s error msg.

I tried googling, but links like:

- ***[How to insert newline in string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085739/how-to-insert-newline-in-string-literal)***
  did not help me.

So please can anyone give a idea to, **"put the returned string in newline if its length is greater than zero" or do nothing?**

EDIT:

Hi All,
 I guess I dint get the proper solution for which I am lookin for. I do not want to append line after each "sb". But if I have a error msg, then, I want to put in NEWLINE.. 
Can someone give me a different solution which caters to my need?..

Comment: What do you mean by "a string _in_ a newline"? That in itself is nonsense.

Comment: Probably just a misuse of a preposition.

Comment: "String in newline" by which I mean, only if ValidatorMethod2() method returns a error msg, it should be put in newline inserted by ValidatorMethod1() else I dont want the new line to come up with BLANK string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can us `String.IsNullOrEmpty` to see if the result has a length greater than 0

For example:

```
string result = ValidatorMethod2();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
   sb.AppendLine(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Any reason you're not just checking that yourself? This will hardly add any noticeable overhead:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String msg;

msg = ValidatorMethod1();
if (msg.Length > 0)
    sb.AppendLine(msg);

msg = ValidatorMethod2();
if (msg.Length > 0)
    sb.AppendLine(msg);
```

In fact, there's no faster way. Even if there'd be some built-in functionality provided by Microsoft, it wouldn't do something significantly different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for each validator:

```
string error = null;

// repeat for each validator
error = ValidatorMethod1();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(error)) sb.AppendLine(error);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try doing something like that (calling AppendLine before each non-empty string if sb contains any text):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String message = ValidatorMethod1();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
  sb.Append(message);

message = ValidatorMethod2();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) {
  if (sb.Length > 0)
    sb.AppendLine();

  sb.Append(message);
}
```

in general case, when you have many validators:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(String result in getValidatorsResults()) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) 
    continue;

  if (sb.Length > 0)
    sb.AppendLine();

  sb.Append(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can i.e. do:

```
string sb1 = ValidatorMethod1();
string sb2 = ValidatorMethod2();
if (sb1 != "") sb.AppendLine(sb1);
if (sb2 != "") sb.AppendLine(sb2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are working with a collection of validation methods, you might want to consider something like this:

```
var validationMethods = new Func<string>[]
{
    () => ValidationMethod1(),
    () => ValidationMethod2(),
    // Add more validtion methods here
};
string error = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, validationMethods.Select(validationMethod => validationMethod()).Where(message=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)));
```

This solution is easily scaleable if you are need to change the number of validation methods you want to run in a sequence, or when you even want to have a dynamic number of validation methods (then you should use something like `List<Func<string>>` instead).