# Enter character in C#

Tags: c#, input, enter

I have this code:

```
while(!sr1.EndOfStream)
{
    radek1 = sr1.ReadLine();
    Console.Write(radek1);
    Console.WriteLine();
    string[] split1 = radek1.Split(new char[] { ' ', '???' });
}
```

I read a string array from a `file.txt` and I need to split with spaces and with enters, so I want to exchange these? For something that represents <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert newline in string literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085739/how-to-insert-newline-in-string-literal)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By enter, you probably mean `New Line`.
In most cases, this would be what you're looking for:

```
string newLine = Environment.NewLine; //Updated to Sergey Volegov's suggested
```

In most cases, `Environment.NewLine` is equal to `"\r\n"`, but sometimes it's only `\n` so it's wiser to use `Environment.NewLine`.

`\r` is the carriage return.
`\n` is a new line.

Think of it as a typewriter. You need to go back to the beginning of the row (`\r`) and then down a line (`\n`)

Due to the fact that `Environment.NewLine` is a string, you're going to want to `Split` on `String`s, and not `Char`s:

```
string[] split1 = radek1.Split(new string[] { " ", Environment.NewLine });
```

Comment: Using Environment.NewLine instead of "\r\n" would be even better

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray();
```

As @Guffa also said you can also have :

```
string[] split1 = radek1.Split(new string[] { " ", Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None));
```

The second one splits based on spaces and new lines.
The first one though, splits by `\r`, and `\n` individually. so For the correct behavior you want to use the second method.

Comment: That's the right one. EOL is highly platform specific.

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: If `Environment.NewLine` is `"\r\n"` then splitting on the array will split on `\r` **or** `\n`, which means that you get an extra empty string from each newline. You have to split on strings to handle that, not on characters.

Comment: @Guffa: You are correct, and i added what you have pointed out to the answer,Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That depends on where the file comes from and how it was created.

If it was created on the same system, it will most likely use the native newline combination for that specific system, and you can use the `Environment.NewLine` constant:

```
string[] split1 = radek1.Split(new string[] { " ", Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Note that `Environment.NewLine` is a string and can contain more than one character, so you need to split on strings, and the call needs a `StringSplitOptions` parameter as there is no overload without it.

If the file comes from a different system (or was created with newlines typical for a different system), you would need to specify that specific string. For example the two character string used in a Windows system:

```
string[] split1 = radek1.Split(new string[] { " ", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

You can also include the most common newline combinations, if you need to handle files coming from different systems:

```
string[] split1 = radek1.Split(new string[] { " ", "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```