# Use of named identifiers in String.Format

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Named string formatting in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159017/named-string-formatting-in-c-sharp)

Has anyone found a way to use named identifiers in the String.Format command?  Having that kind of functionality would be helpful for "old" folks like us with failing memories.  I mean since the braces are a reserved character in this command anyway, does the text within it really matter?

Does MVC follow roughly the same syntax when defining a route?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

So instead of using:

```
String.Format("http://foobar.com/calendar/{0}/{1}", selectedYear, selectedMonth);
```

Wouldn't it follow to see:

```
String.Format("http://foobar.com/calendar/{year}/{month}", selectedYear, selectedMonth);
```

Or even:

```
String.Format("http://foobar.com/calendar/{year}/{month}", new {selectedYear, selectedMonth});
```

The second statement doesn't compile obviously but I was wondering if someone had found a way to implement that functionality.

Comment: IMO, this is over-engineering a solution for a problem that doesn't exist. Sorry.