# Html page to string

Tags: c#, html, string, smtpclient

I am sending emails to my users in HTML format. There is lots of editing there, like user name, user birthday and many other details.

Now, I don't want my code to be look like this:

```
String message = "hello " + "David\n" + "congratulation for your " + birthday + "\nPleas visit our site\n" + siteLink + " to get your bonus";
```

Is there any C# tools I can use to make it easy editing?

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to be able to specify named tokens in a single string so that the HTML is easy to read and edit, like so:

```
"Hello {FirstName},\nPlease visit our site:\n{SiteLink}"
```

Take a look at this answer for some ways to do that: [Named string formatting in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159017/named-string-formatting-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 1):

```
string customBody = "<a href=\"www.oursite.com\">www.oursite.com</a>";
string htmlBody = String.Format("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">";
        body += "<HTML><HEAD><META http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\">";
        body += "</HEAD><BODY><DIV>{0}</DIV></BODY></HTML>", customBody);

var message = new MailMessage(from, to);
var mimeType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html");
var alternate = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, mimeType);
message.AlternateViews.Add(alternate);        
message.IsBodyHTML = true;
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

See MSDN:

- [Alternative Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx)
- [MailMessage.IsBodyHtml Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx)

Comment: How doe's it makes it easy for editing? I got another 20 parameters to push there...

Comment: It is not a question of HTML email format but anyway you can use `StringBuilder` or `string.Format` to conditionally build HTML body, or can create some helper methods

Comment: Anyways you need to fill in only `customBody` string, `htmlBody` is a standart header/footer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign html code to `message body`

```
message.Body = "<b> This is a bold Text </b>";
message.IsBodyHTML = true;
```

Also, you can take advantage of [MailDefinition Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx). Check [this link](http://martinnormark.com/generate-html-e-mail-body-in-c-using-templates) for the usage of this class.

Answer (score 0):

Use isHtmlBody property, from MailMessage

Example:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.Body= "example of <a href='www.something.com'>Link</a>";
msg.IsBodyHtml = True;
...    
smtp.send(msg)
```

see :

[IsBodyHtml Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx)

[Example](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/3.1.2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[string.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) might be what you are after.

`string.Format()` replaces each format item in a specified string with the text equivalent of a corresponding object's value.

So for instance

```
 string.Format("Dear {0} {1}, You are {2} today.",
       person.Title, person.Lastname, person.Age);
```