# C#: can labels be used instead of numbers with String.Format?

Tags: c#, .net

Refering to this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx

it seems that it is not possible with the String.Format method to use labels instead of indices in the format string parameter.

Is there some syntax or functionality native to the .Net Framework that allows using labels instead of 0,1,...,N ?

As an example, how can this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{0}{1}", "foo", "bar"));
```

become something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{foo}{bar}{foo}{bar}", 
                                new { foo = "foo", bar = "bar" }));
```

Comment: No there isn't... Although it wouldn't be too hard to write that yourself.

Comment: That would be a neat way of doing it. I guess its not like that because the `Format` syntax comes from C which doesn't work like this. You could code up your own implementation with an extension method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Named string formatting in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159017/named-string-formatting-in-c-sharp)

Comment: ha thanks, I hadn't found that one, the accepted answer of that question seems to be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nice question 
after opening reflector

there isnt a way :

it counts in digits only :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Phil Haack wrote a blog about a way to do this:

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/04/fun-with-named-formats-string-parsing-and-edge-cases.aspx

There is no built-in way in .NET to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Ref: [C#: String.Inject() - Format strings by key tokens](http://mo.notono.us/2008/07/c-stringinject-format-strings-by-key.html)

```
string myString = "{foo} is {bar} and {yadi} is {yada}".Inject(o);
```

it accepts an object, IDictionary or HashTable and replaces the property name/key tokens with the instance values.  Since it uses string.Format internally, it uses the [string.Format-like custom formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy%28loband%29.aspx).

> .Net does not have such implementation internally.  you can use
>   [Custom formatting with ICustomFormatProvider Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx#Custom).
>
> The syntax of a format item is as follows:
>
> ```
> {index[,length][:formatString]}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As of C# 6, you can use [Interpolated Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings):

```
string foo = "foo1";
string bar = "bar2";
Console.WriteLine($"{foo} {bar} {foo} {bar}");
```

Which will output:

> foo1 bar2 foo1 bar2