# Parametrized string syntax with named parameters

Tags: c#, named-parameters

I'm writing a C# app. I'm targeting it to .NET 4.5.1.

There is a translation service in my app, where the translated strings are stored in a database. A string can contain any number of parameters with any type.

```
string formatString = GetFormatStringFromDB();

Dictionary<string,object> parameters = GetNamedParametersFromSomewhere();

var result = Format(formatString, parameters);
```

The [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) syntax looks like an ideal candidate for this.

Like:

```
string formatString = "{0} is married to {1}, and they have a child of age {2}"; // note that this should still come from the DB

Dictionary<string,object> parameters = GetNamedParametersFromSomewhere();

var result = string.Format(formatString, parameters.Select(o => o.Value)); // I might need to convert this to an array.
```

### What is my problem with this

I want the parameters to be named. I don't want to identify parameters with a numerical index: It's non descriptive and I will most likely confuse/mix them up in translations.

### What I want

A syntax where I can represent parameters by their names like:

```
string formatString = "{wife} is married to {husband}, and they have a child of age {childAge}";
```

Hey this looks similar to the new [String Interpolation](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/570614) syntax in C# vNext! Would I be able to use that?

No:

1. It's a vNext feature, I need a solution for .NET 4.5.1.
2. It's not even what I need. It's just for inline strings where the parameters - which are already available - get automatically replaced. It can not be stored, and later evaluated for different sets of parameters. Using the new `FormattedString` class seems way too confusing to me, but it might be a solution although I would need to port it back to the current .NET and I would need some help on that (and also on properly using it).

Also with Composite Formatting it is possible to format a datetime or an int like: `"birthday: {0:d}"`. It's extremely useful for translations as different languages and cultures tend to represent these in quite different formats. I would not want to lose that functionality.

### What I ask for here

A syntax I could use. Some functions to feed to parameters to the string and get the result.

Like:

```
string formatString = GetFormatStringFromDB();
// "Age: {age}, Birthday: {birthday:d}"

Dictionary<string,object> parameters = GetNamedParametersFromSomewhere();
// { "age": (int)10, "birthday": (DateTime)1988-01-01 }

var result = myOwnFormat(formatString, parameters);
//result should be "Age: 10, Birthday: 12/30/2011"
```

Should I roll my own syntax, and parser for it? Is there something similar already implemented?

**EDIT:**

I reworded the whole question describing the problem better (hopefully), pointing out what I ask for.

Comment: Did you look at the `FormattedString` part of the page you linked to? If so, it's not clear what you're looking for... if you could give an example of what you're trying to do, that would be useful.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have written an example on what I'm trying to do. Is it useful?

Comment: Yes, that's much clearer... although there's no such thing as "C# 4.5.1". There's C#, and there's .NET 4.5.1. You might be able to do something with `FormattedString` and poke your own values in... it's hard to tell as the current preview doesn't support it. (I want it to be called `FormattableString`, mind you.) Bear in mind that the format is much broader than just a set of values - it's *expressions* that can be evaluated. You might want to write your own parser after all...

Comment: Would any of the solutions mentioned here be of use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159017/named-string-formatting-in-c-sharp ?

Comment: Thank you @BigT there are plenty of suitable answers there, I'm still in the middle of exploring them but yes, they are of use.

Answer (score 0):

Even as late as the current .net core versions, run time interpolation is not supported. However, this code will work for both .net core, and .net framework.

I rolled my own for this very same scenario. I found the idea off of another stack overflow post. Forgot where, else I would credit them. There is a current issue that I need to work around where it will not allow literal braces "{".

Source code: https://gist.github.com/tcartwright/cca1247a741eaf9f191003fe3d599edd

Example usage:

```
public class Customer {
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
    
// concrete poco
var customer = new Customer { Name = "Microsoft", Id = 1234 };

var str = "Customer: {customer.Name}, id: {customer.Id}"
    .ToFormattedString(new NamedParameter("customer", customer));

Console.WriteLine(str);

// using with a dynamic
dynamic customer2 = new { Name = "Stack Overflow", Id = 8675309 };

str = "Customer: {customer.Name}, id: {customer.Id}"
    .ToFormattedString(new NamedParameter("customer", customer2));
    
Console.WriteLine(str);
```