# String interpolation using a string

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

Following is a String interpolation example. If `apple` is equals to `apple` it returns `yes` or else `no`.

```
var result = $"{("apple" == "apple" ? "yes" : "no")}";
```

What I need to do is to assign a string

```
string text= "{(apple == apple ? yes: no)}";
var result = $"{text}";
```

I expected `var result` will be `yes`. As its similar to the above code. However, the result I get is the string `text` it self.

My question: How can I pass a string similar to `"{(apple == apple ? yes: no)}"`and get an output like `yes` or `no` ?

Comment: You can't, at least not with that specific language feature. It doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Meta-Knight it is `{(apple == apple ? yes: no)}` (May be I should have rephased it as the output of the variable text).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass interpolated strings as parameter to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31987232/is-it-possible-to-pass-interpolated-strings-as-parameter-to-a-method)

Comment: Is there any other way i could achieve this ?

Comment: See the proposed duplicate. I *think* you may be able to get something working with `FormattableString` but I haven't personally used it yet.

Comment: Don't forget the whole reason for string interpolation is `String interpolation provides a more readable and convenient syntax to create formatted strings`. It might make more sense to do this without interpolation.

Answer (score 2):

If all you wanted was to return "yes" or "no" then you wouldn't need interpolation because there's nothing to interpolate. You could just do this:

```
var result = something == "apple" ? "yes" : "no";
```

If you needed some concatenation - in other words, you had to interpolate something - you could do this:

```
var something = "apple";
var result = $"Is it an apple? {(something == "apple" ? "yes" : "no")}!";
```

Returns

> Is it an apple? yes!

The entire conditional expression needs to be in parenthesis.

For readability it might make sense to break it up into steps anyway.

```
var something = "apple";
var yesOrNo = something == "apple" ? "yes" : "no";
var result = $"Is it an apple? {yesOrNo}!";
```

Comment: What if the input string is ONLY `"{(apple == apple ? yes: no)}"`. And, I need to output the answer YES or NO. Do I have to split the string and construct an Equation as shown in your example ? Or is there any other way I could do this ?

Comment: In that case you would be trying to place code inside of a string literal and interpret it at runtime. Such a thing exists but it's way off the beaten path, like trying to generate classes dynamically at runtime. Unless you're trying to build a compiler then it's almost certainly something that you wouldn't want to do.

Answer (score 1):

String interpolation with `$` does not take place at *run time*. It is evaluated at *compile time*. Only the expression between the curly braces is evaluated at run time.

When you want to do the evaluation *later* at run time you need to use a *delegate*:

```
Func<string> textfactory = () => "apple" == "apple" ? "yes" : "no";
var result = $"{ textfactory() }";
```

or just

```
var result = textfactory();
```

since there is nothing to interpolate but the string itself.

The delegate can be passed around, e.g. as function argument.

Answer (score 0):

Can't. Sense of interpolation - allow to inject output of code inside string. Compiler should know what to inject. In second case string =text= can contain anything, it's more for interpreter, not compiler. Now code work way it should. Imho.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the same syntax that you were looking for, but this works:

```
 public class yourFruitStand
 {
      private string yourFruitName;
      public bool YourFruitName
      {
           get
           {
               return yourFruitName;
           }
           set
           {
               yourFruitName = value;

               if(yourFruitName == "apple")
               {
                    yesOrNo = true;
               }
               else
               {
                    yesOrNo = false;
               }
           }
      }
      private bool yesOrNo;
      public bool yesOrNo
      {
           get
           {
               return yesOrNo;
           }
           set
           {
               yesOrNo = value;
           }
      }
 }
```